# How to convert DateTime to VarChar

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-convert

I need to convert a value which is in a `DateTime` variable into a `varchar` variable formatted as `yyyy-mm-dd` format (without time part).

How do I do that?

Comment: `CONVERT`, see [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Comment: be aware that YYYY-MM-DD is ambiguous, depending on your language settings. best to use ISO standard YYYYMMDD, see [this blog post](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2008/01/05/date-format-inconsistency-yyyy-mm-dd-or-yyyymmdd-when-2007-04-10-is-4th-october.aspx)

Answer (score 274, accepted):

With Microsoft Sql Server:

```
--
-- Create test case
--
DECLARE @myDateTime DATETIME
SET @myDateTime = '2008-05-03'

--
-- Convert string
--
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @myDateTime, 120), 10)
```

Comment: For those of you who may be interested, this would perform better if you change VARCHAR to CHAR.

See this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59667/why-would-i-ever-pick-char-over-varchar-in-sql) for more details. Essentially, there are 2 bytes of overhead involved in VARCHAR vs CHAR. In this scenario, we know that your string will always be 10 characters, so CHAR is appropriate.

Comment: Side note, from what I've seen, too bad none of the formats honors whatever the DATEFORMAT is set to, maybe there is another way.

Comment: Is there any reason to use `LEFT(.., 10)` instead of `CONVERT(CHAR(10), ...)`? Also those working with the newer versions of SQL Server than 2005(!) should check out [the answer by Zar Shardan](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17713768/1026) suggesting a solution based on `FORMAT(date_value, format_string)` function.

Comment: @Nickolay besides `FORMAT()` is too slow relative to `convert(char(10),...)`

Answer (score 420):

Here's some test sql for all the styles.

```
DECLARE @now datetime
SET @now = GETDATE()
select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 0) as output, 0 as style 
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 1), 1
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 2), 2
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 3), 3
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 4), 4
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 5), 5
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 6), 6
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 7), 7
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 8), 8
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 9), 9
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 10), 10
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 11), 11
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 12), 12
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 13), 13
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 14), 14
--15 to 19 not valid
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 20), 20
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 21), 21
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 22), 22
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 23), 23
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 24), 24
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 25), 25
--26 to 99 not valid
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 100), 100
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 101), 101
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 102), 102
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 103), 103
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 104), 104
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 105), 105
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 106), 106
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 107), 107
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 108), 108
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 109), 109
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 110), 110
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 111), 111
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 112), 112
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 113), 113
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 114), 114
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 120), 120
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 121), 121
--122 to 125 not valid
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 126), 126
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 127), 127
--128, 129 not valid
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 130), 130
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 131), 131
--132 not valid
order BY style
```

Here's the result

```
output                   style
Apr 28 2014  9:31AM          0
04/28/14                     1
14.04.28                     2
28/04/14                     3
28.04.14                     4
28-04-14                     5
28 Apr 14                    6
Apr 28, 14                   7
09:31:28                     8
Apr 28 2014  9:31:28:580AM   9
04-28-14                     10
14/04/28                     11
140428                       12
28 Apr 2014 09:31:28:580     13
09:31:28:580                 14
2014-04-28 09:31:28          20
2014-04-28 09:31:28.580      21
04/28/14  9:31:28 AM         22
2014-04-28                   23
09:31:28                     24
2014-04-28 09:31:28.580      25
Apr 28 2014  9:31AM          100
04/28/2014                   101
2014.04.28                   102
28/04/2014                   103
28.04.2014                   104
28-04-2014                   105
28 Apr 2014                  106
Apr 28, 2014                 107
09:31:28                     108
Apr 28 2014  9:31:28:580AM   109
04-28-2014                   110
2014/04/28                   111
20140428                     112
28 Apr 2014 09:31:28:580     113
09:31:28:580                 114
2014-04-28 09:31:28          120
2014-04-28 09:31:28.580      121
2014-04-28T09:31:28.580      126
2014-04-28T09:31:28.580      127
28 جمادى الثانية 1435  9:31:28:580AM    130
28/06/1435  9:31:28:580AM    131
```

Make `nvarchar(max)` shorter to trim the time. For example:

```
select convert(nvarchar(11), GETDATE(), 0)
union select convert(nvarchar(max), GETDATE(), 0)
```

outputs:

```
May 18 2018
May 18 2018  9:57AM
```

Comment: Here Sometimes we want like  `dd-mm` or `jun - 28`. There is any option??

Comment: Works for SQL Server 2005 so this is great for those of us that are still unfortunately meddling with older systems. Upgrading to 2014 soon, excited!

Comment: I wanna format close to 101 -- 101 = 04/28/2014 , I wanna without zero in the month , output  4/28/2014, is it applicable ?

Comment: Isn't the timezone identifier Z missing in style 127.

Comment: @Atishay "only supported when casting from character data to datetime or smalldatetime". See the footnotes 6 and 7 at https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

Comment: I Suggest not to use nvarchar(max) instead use varchar(50) or some suitable value. Otherwise, it might cause some errors in some systems. In my case, Crystal report can't detect nvarchar(max) fields As Dynamic Parameter

Answer (score 188):

Try the following:

```
CONVERT(varchar(10), [MyDateTimecolumn], 20)
```

For a full date time and not just date do:

```
CONVERT(varchar(23), [MyDateTimecolumn], 121)
```

See this page for convert styles:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx
OR
[SQL Server CONVERT() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp)

Answer (score 40):

SQL Server 2012 has a new function , FORMAT: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634924.aspx

and you can use custom date time format strings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634398.aspx

These pages imply it is also available on SQL2008R2, but I don't have one handy to test if that's the case.

Example usage (Australian datetime):

```
FORMAT(VALUE,'dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt')
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use `DATEPART(DATEPART, VARIABLE)`. For example:

```sql
DECLARE @DAY INT 
DECLARE @MONTH INT
DECLARE @YEAR INT
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME
@DATE = GETDATE()
SELECT @DAY = DATEPART(DAY,@DATE)
SELECT @MONTH = DATEPART(MONTH,@DATE)
SELECT @YEAR = DATEPART(YEAR,@DATE)
```

Answer (score 8):

Either `Cast` or `Convert`:

Syntax for `CAST`:

```
CAST ( expression AS data_type [ (length ) ])
```

Syntax for `CONVERT`:

```
CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Actually since you asked for a specific format:

```
REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(10), Date, 102), '.', '-')
```

Answer (score 7):

-- This gives you the time as 0 in format 'yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00.000'

```
SELECT CAST( CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 101) AS DATETIME) ;
```

Answer (score 6):

With Microsoft SQL Server:

Use Syntax for CONVERT:

```
CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )
```

Example:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar,d.dateValue,1-9)
```

For the style you can find more info here: [MSDN - Cast and Convert (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

For SQL Server 2008+ You can use CONVERT and FORMAT together.

For example, for European style (e.g. Germany) timestamp:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss', 'de-DE'))
```

Comment: `FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss', 'de-DE')` already returns varchar with the given format, what is the reason for calling convert on it?

Comment: It returns nvarchar, not varchar.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GetDate(),102)
```

Then you would need to replace the "." with "-".

Here is a site that helps
http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1145

Answer (score 3):

```
declare @dt datetime

set @dt = getdate()

select convert(char(10),@dt,120)
```

I have fixed data length of `char(10)` as you want a specific string format.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
select replace(convert(varchar, getdate(), 111),'/','-');
```

More on [ms sql tips](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1145)

Answer (score 3):

The OP mentioned **datetime** format.  For me, the time part gets in the way.
I think it's a bit cleaner to remove the time portion (by casting datetime to date) before formatting.

```
convert( varchar(10), convert( date, @yourDate ) , 111 )
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how I do it:

```sql
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), DATE1, 103) )
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this SQL:

```
select REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),GETDATE(),103),'/','_') + '_'+ 
       REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),GETDATE(),114),':','_')
```

Answer (score 2):

The shortest and the simplest way is :

```
DECLARE @now AS DATETIME = GETDATE()

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, @now, 23)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your date in many formats, the syntaxe is simple to use :

```
CONVERT('TheTypeYouWant', 'TheDateToConvert', 'TheCodeForFormating' * )
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), DATE_OF_DAY, 103) => 15/09/2016
```

- The code is an integer, here 3 is the third formating without century, if you want the century just change the code to 103.

**In your case**, i've just converted and restrict size by nvarchar(10) like this :

```
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), MY_DATE_TIME, 120) => 2016-09-15
```

See more at : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

**Another solution** (if your date is a Datetime) is a simple **CAST** :

```
CAST(MY_DATE_TIME as DATE) => 2016-09-15
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not say which database, but with mysql here is an easy way to get a date from a timestamp (and the varchar type conversion should happen automatically):

```
mysql> select date(now());
+-------------+
| date(now()) |
+-------------+
| 2008-09-16  | 
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Check again:  he specified sql server via a tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 23)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @DateTime DATETIME
SET @DateTime = '2018-11-23 10:03:23'
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),@DateTime,121 )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, FORMAT(GETDATE(), N'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt')),'.', '/')
```

will give `05/05/2020 10:41:05 AM` as a result

Comment: Every resource I could find used the 'code number' to define the format, and it wasn't working for me. This one does, and in my opinion, is much better if you take a bit of time to learn the format.

Answer (score 1):

Simple use "Convert" and then use "Format" to get your desire date format

```
DECLARE @myDateTime DATETIME
SET @myDateTime = '2008-05-03'

SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(date, @myDateTime ),'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TO_SAP_DATETIME(@input datetime)
RETURNS VARCHAR(14)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @ret VARCHAR(14)
    SET @ret = COALESCE(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), @input, 25),'-',''),' ',''),':',''),1,14),'00000000000000');
    RETURN @ret
END
```

Answer (score -3):

You don't say what language but I am assuming `C#/.NET` because it has a native `DateTime` data type. In that case just convert it using the `ToString` method and use a format specifier such as:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Today;
string result = d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

However, I would caution against using this in a database query or concatenated into a SQL statement. Databases require a specific formatting string to be used. You are better off zeroing out the time part and using the DateTime as a SQL parameter if that is what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: In the question, it's mentioned "I am working on a query in Sql Server 2005".

Comment: @InkHeart and all the down-voters - This answer was posted in 2008. If you check the history of edits for the original question there were no tags and/or any other technology-related information included.