# Sql datatype conversion

Tags: sql

we need to change one column i.e., Start_Date of datatype datetime to bigint.
For existing datas we have records like '2010-01-01 00:00:00' which should be converted into bigint and should return value like '20100101000000'.
I tried with convert and cast fn but i am not getting the desire output.
Can anyone help me out on this.

Comment: please tell us which database server you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74385/how-to-convert-datetime-to-varchar) datetime to varchar.

Then do a [replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) for '-' with empty char ''

Comment: ...and replace `' '` (space) and `':'` (colon) too

Answer (score 1):

Hope This will help

```
    SELECT  DATENAME(year, Datetime_Colum)+''+
            SUBSTRING( CAST(CONVERT(DATE,Datetime_Colum,101)AS VARCHAR(8)),6,2)+''+
            DATENAME(DAY, Datetime_Colum)+''+
            DATENAME(hour, Datetime_Colum)+''+
            DATENAME(minute, Datetime_Colum)+''+
            DATENAME(second, Datetime_Colum)
    FROM    [dbo].[Table]
```

--//===================================================================

Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION udf_Convert_Datetime_To_INT 
(
    @DATETIME DATETIME
)

RETURNS BIGINT
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Result BIGINT

SELECT @Result =   CAST(( DATENAME(YEAR,@DATETIME) +''+
                    SUBSTRING( CAST(CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE(),101)AS VARCHAR(8)),6,2)+''+
                    DATENAME(DAY,@DATETIME)+''+
                    DATENAME(hour, @DATETIME)+''+
                    DATENAME(minute, @DATETIME)+''+
                    DATENAME(second, @DATETIME)) AS BIGINT)
RETURN @Result

END
GO

PRINT DBO.udf_Convert_Datetime_To_INT (GETDATE())
```

Result :  20110511152843

Answer (score 0):

```
update Table_1 set xnew=REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE (CONVERT(VARCHAR,x,20) , '-' , '' ),':',''),' ','')
```

add new field xnew varchar(50) , then you can convert it into bigint.. 
x is your datetime field..