# SQL DW Convert [datetime2](7) to [bigint]

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

In SQL `DataWahouse` Database, I want to write an query to convert `[datetime2](7)` to `bigint`

Table :1

```
[StartTime] [datetime2](7) NULL
```

Table :2

```
[StartTime] [bigint] NULL


Select * FROM  Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 
ON Table1.StartTime = Table2.StartTime  -- Geting error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work.

datetime2 is not an integer. The following reference discusses its internal data structure:
https://sqlfascination.com/2009/10/11/what-is-the-sql-server-2008-datetime2-internal-structure/

What is the representation of your T2.StartTime? Is it milliseconds from a starting point? The following reference may help:
[MSSQL - Convert milliseconds since 1970 to datetime2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14716744/mssql-convert-milliseconds-since-1970-to-datetime2)

That said, please don't join like this, performance will be terrible. Further, the logic of a join between a datetime2 and a datetime2 created from an integer is very scarey ... if these are both supposed to be DATES, then store them as dates. Otherwise, be prepared for a very high number of missed join candidates due to the precision issues you're going to encounter.

Comment: Ok, in this case i will use both the columns as date.

Comment: I want to find the difference between dates for specific hours.. say data join for same date but hours can be + or - 6 hours in difference..

Comment: I want to join the values of 2 tables  dates for specific minutes .. say data join for same date but hours can be + or - 10 minutes in difference..

Answer (score 0):

`Table1.StartTime` and `Table2.StartTime` are different data types, so when you run your query, it gets error.

Azure SQL DataWahouse Database supports `datetime2` and `bigint`.

You can reference this blob, it shows you [convert datetime to bigint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949916/convert-datetime-to-bigint).

See the demo SQL:

```
update Table1 set StartTime=REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE (CONVERT(VARCHAR,x,20) , '-' , '' ),':',''),' ','')
```

Reference 2:[Sql datatype conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946046/sql-datatype-conversion/5946127#5946127)

Hope this helps.