# Format() function doesn't work?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008, format

I am trying to execute following built-in function in sql but it gives me error that this  function doesn't exist

my query:

```
select EmpId, EmpName, format(EmpJoinDate, "YYYY-DD-MM") as date from Employee
```

Error i am getting:

```
'format' is not a recognized built-in function name
```

What may be  the problem, or what am i doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`Convert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) function instead. Example:

```
select convert(varchar(5), GETDATE(), 126) + convert(varchar(5), GETDATE(), 105)
```

Comment: Because it does not exist in SQL Server, are you thinking of Access?

Comment: Because as the error message says, it's not a valid function.

Comment: @user, I don't see `format` on the list of t-sql functions at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189826(SQL.90).aspx, so I don't expect that it would work.  Are you perhaps thinking of another database?

Comment: i was looking at this  [site](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_format.asp) and i tried using format() but it didnt work. is w3schools wrong?

Comment: Yes. w3schools is terrible; see http://w3fools.com/ - whatever SQL dialect its talking about is not T-SQL.

Comment: @polishchuk: i m sorry but i didnt   downvoted you, i dont have that privilege yet.

Comment: @ Alex K: thanks! i should have read SQL book instead of w3school.

Comment: @user728885, I'm sorry, I got heated

Comment: Format is in T-SQL from version 2012 on.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 5):

That's because `FORMAT()` is not a built-in function in SQL 2005. You need to use the `CONVERT()` function:

```
SELECT
    EmpId,
    EmpName,
    REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), EmpJoinDate, 102), '.', '-') AS date
FROM
    Employee
```

A few caveats though... "date" is a reserved word I believe, so I wouldn't suggest using that, even as a column alias. Also, the above actually gives YYYY-MM-DD. YYYY-DD-MM is pretty rare I believe. If you truly want that you'll need to either concatenate things together yourself with the `DATEPART` and `CAST` functions or concatenate things using `SUBSTRING` with `CONVERT`.

Do a search on `CONVERT` and you should be able to find all of the various formats supported. The one that I used above (102) is for YYYY.MM.DD, so I did a replace to give the hyphens instead.

Comment: Why bother replacing when there's a `convert(varchar(10), EmpJoinDate, 23)` to format straight to "YYYY-DD-MM"? I kinda expected that to be the most popular answer...

Answer (score 3):

According to MSDN documentation, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505(SQL.110).aspx, it is a built-in function.  I am assuming it has not been implemented.

Comment: That page is specifically for SQL Server "Denali" (now officially SQL Server 2012) as indicated immediately below the title: if it was supported in other versions this text would be a dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers will work but use some hacky string replace and concats. Although you could set `date_style` to 23 to convert straight to "YYYY-DD-MM" format:

```
convert(varchar(10), EmpJoinDate, 23)
```

For a complete list of formats I'd like to refer to this awesome SO-answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19537658/2140636