# sql server convert date to string MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008.

I have the following:

```
    select convert(varchar(20),fmdate) from Sery
```

How do I convert the date to string such that it show as MM/DD/YYYY

Answer (score 83, accepted):

That task should be done by the next layer up in your software stack. SQL is a data repository, not a presentation system

You can do it with

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), fmdate(), 101)
```

But you shouldn't

Comment: There are actually several reasons to have the database do this, including time/date difference at server location, especially if daylight savings factors into it. Yes, it does force what is likely a locale-specific format, though.

Comment: @zanlok A locale specific format would generally be a bad idea

Comment: I would say you don't want to store a formatted date in your database, but if you're for some reason exporting the field (say... to a .csv file) you could have a very valid reason for doing so.

Comment: There are plenty of reasons to use this. This time my reason being I am using this to format a date for presentation in body of sp_send_dbmail...

Answer (score 30):

```
select convert(varchar(10), fmdate, 101) from sery
```

101 is a style argument.

Rest of 'em can be found here.

[CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL) - Date and time styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql#date-and-time-styles)

Answer (score 9):

*As of SQL Server 2012+*, you can use [`FORMAT(value, format [, culture ])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql)

Where the `format` param takes any valid [standard format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) or [custom formatting string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

**Example**:

```sql
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'MM/dd/yyyy')
```

**Further Reading**:

- [How to convert DateTime to VarChar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74385/1366033)
- [How to convert date to a format `mm/dd/yyyy`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18568410/1366033)

Answer (score 5):

```
select convert(varchar(10), cast(fmdate as date), 101) from sery
```

Without cast I was not getting fmdate converted, so fmdate was a string.

Comment: Source- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18568410/how-to-convert-date-to-a-format-mm-dd-yyyy