# How to get a particular date format ('dd-MMM-yyyy') in SELECT query SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, date, select, date-format

I am using `CONVERT(data_type(length),expression,style)` function to change the format of a date in a SELECT query.

> Declare @dt nvarchar(20)
>
> Select @dt = Convert(nvarchar(20), SalesDate, 113)  FROM SalesTable

The format I need is 'dd-MMM-yyyy' (eg. '05-Jul-2013') but I could not find the proper style number (eg. 113) for this particular format. Can any one help me with that please?

Comment: It's usually better to do this formatting closer to the user (e.g. in the report generator, or in whatever other code you're writing that's presenting the results to the user)

Comment: For folks with SQL Server 2012+, you can use [`FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'dd-MMM-yyyy')`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58925034/1366033)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try this:

```
Declare @dt NVARCHAR(20)

Select 
    @dt = REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(15), SalesDate, 106),' ',' - ') 
FROM SalesTable
```

Comment: Great Answer..exactly what I was looking for @Abhishek Jain

Comment: Use trim functions if your date has time and you don't want to see the trailing dashes REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(CONVERT(CHAR(15), SalesDate, 106))),' ','-')

Answer (score 14):

```
select CONVERT(NVARCHAR, SYSDATETIME(), 106) AS [DD-MON-YYYY]
```

or else

```
select REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,GETDATE(), 106), ' ', '-')
```

both works fine

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't look like DD-MMM-YYYY is supported by default (at least, with dash as separator). However, using the AS clause, you should be able to do something like:

`SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), SYSDATETIME(), 106) AS [DD-MON-YYYY]`

See here: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/sql-server-2008-date-format.aspx

Answer (score 5):

I Think this is the best way to do it.

```
REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,CAST(WeekEnding AS DATETIME), 106), ' ', '-')
```

Because you do not have to use `varchar(11)` or `varchar(10)` that can make problem in future.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Convert(varchar(10),CONVERT(date,'columnname',105),105) as "end";
```

OR

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(event_enddate AS DATE), 105) AS [end];
```

will return the particular date in the format of 'dd-mm-yyyy'

The result would be like this..

```
04-07-2016
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select convert(varchar(11), transfer_date, 106)
```

got me my desired result of date formatted as 07 Mar 2018

My column `transfer_date` is a datetime type column and I am using SQL Server 2017 on azure

Answer (score 1):

select FORMAT(getdate(), 'dd-MMM-yyyy') as DateToday

Answer (score 0):

Other answers here seem to return columns that are quite wide.

This answer returns a varchar(11) which is all that is required for a date in dd-Mon-yyyy format.

```
'SalesDate' = CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),SalesDate, 106), ' ', '-')),
```

Try also:

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),getdate(), 106), ' ', '-'))
```

As of today, this gives a result as per: 22-Jul-2021

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT empl_id, empl_name, FORMAT(empl_dob,'dd-MMM-yyyy') FROM [company_XYZ].[dbo].[tbl_empl]
```

The '*empl_dob*' is the date field which is being formatted in '*dd-MMM-yyyy*' for example (15-JAN-1984) of the database '*company_XYZ*' and table '*tbl_empl*'.