# SQL Server Date conversion issue : yyyy-mm-dd should become as dd-mm-yyyy through query

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a date column where the date format is

```
2016-07-24
```

in SQL Server now. Is there any possible way to retrieve the date format as

```
24-07-2016
```

through a select statement? 
and My presently I am using this query

```
Convert(varchar(10),CONVERT(date,event_enddate,105),126) as "end"
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: A date column has no Format! If your column of date type char, you should convert it

Comment: @Jens, we could use convert function to get formatted

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Comment: what is the data type for column `event_enddate` ?

Comment: Target style `dd-mm-yyyy` is time style 105. So I guess you should place 126 inside and 105 outside

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a particular date format ('dd-MMM-yyyy') in SELECT query SQL Server 2008 R2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202260/how-to-get-a-particular-date-format-dd-mmm-yyyy-in-select-query-sql-server-2)

Comment: `Convert(varchar(10), event_enddate,105) as [end]`?

Comment: @squirrel, datetime

Comment: here something...
`SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 105) — dd-mm-yyyy`

https://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/

Comment: don't do it in SQL query. You are only returning a string to your application. Perform the formatting in your front end application

Comment: @10086, I tried it but it shows me error near to "end"

Comment: @Keynes You should replace double quote `"end"` to `[end]`, I think.

Comment: CONVERT(date,event_enddate,105),105) as "end" . This i tried and received desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(event_enddate AS DATE),103), '/', '-') AS [end]
```

or

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(event_enddate AS DATE), 105) AS [end]
```

will return your expected format.

More over add square bracket `[ ]` instead of double quotes `" "` for your alias name

---

Sample execution with GETDATE(): [Reference](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE),105) AS [end]
```

Output:

```
04-07-2016
```

Comment: a bit overkill. Actually not really a bit :)

Comment: MSDN provides functions to converts date values directly. I don't think you need REPLACE.

Comment: @MincongHuang: Yeah, I missed. Thanks for notify.

Comment: @Arulkumar, I get error like this, Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Comment: @Keynes:  It returns the proper data. Check the [fiddler](http://rextester.com/GHVP67275)

Comment: @Arulkumar, yes buddy, it has worked fine now, and i tried another way that also worked :) Convert(varchar(10),CONVERT(date,'columnname',105),105) as "end";

Comment: @Keynes: In the above query `CONVERT(date,'columnname',105)` is not needed. Simply replace with `columnname` is enough, as you mentioned in the comments, the particular column already is in `datetime`.

Answer (score 1):

Were you looking for the below?

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 105)
```

For other formats, check [this](https://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/).

Comment: CONVERT(date,event_enddate,105),105) as "end", should i have to do like this?