# how to convert date to a format `mm/dd/yyyy`

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm having a `sql table` with date column named `CREATED_TS` which holds the dates in different format eg. as shown below

```
Feb 20 2012 12:00AM
11/29/12  8:20:53 PM          
Feb 20 2012 12:00AM
11/29/12  8:20:53 PM          
Feb 20 2012 12:00AM
11/29/12  8:20:53 PM          
Nov 16 2011 12:00AM
Feb 20 2012 12:00AM
11/29/12  8:20:52 PM
```

Now I want to convert these to format `mm\dd\yyyy` before as i am comparing the dates in `WHERE` clause of my `SELECT` query.

I tried using

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CREATED_TS,101)
```

but got the result as,

```
Feb 20 201
11/29/12  
Feb 20 201
11/29/12  
Feb 20 201
11/29/12  
Nov 16 201
Feb 20 201
11/29/12
```

I need the result as eg. `02/20/2012` in order to compare.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your problem is because you are storing dates as varchars! There is no good reason to do this ever. Store dates as dates! [Please give this article a read](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Comment: @GarethD He should actually store them as datetime

Comment: Surprised no one linked the Date and Time Styles documentation chart https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles

Answer (score 57, accepted):

As your data already in varchar, you have to convert it into date first:

```
select convert(varchar(10), cast(ts as date), 101) from <your table>
```

Comment: This is correct with regard to converting to date first, but `111` is for `yyyy/mm/dd`, the OP already has the right style (101).

Comment: got the required output using your suggestion but needed  to convert the date i wanted to compare to this format as well..

Comment: convert(varchar(10), <your date>, 111). But, honestly, it's worth to think about storing and comparing your dates as dates

Comment: @GarethD wow after 4 years I've found your comment. Thanks for pointing out, updated

Answer (score 28):

Use [`CONVERT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) with the `Value` specifier of `101`, whilst casting your data to `date`:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(Created_TS AS DATE), 101)
```

Comment: @DarrenDavies Learned from the mighty Dazefs ;)

Comment: 111 is for `yyyy/mm/dd`, the OP has the right style (101) the problem is that the column is already a varchar and not a date, so the style is not being applied.

Answer (score 5):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEFT(created_ts, 1) LIKE '[0-9]' 
            THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(datetime, created_ts,   1), 101)
            ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(datetime, created_ts, 109), 101)
      END created_ts
  FROM table1
```

Output:

```
| CREATED_TS |
|------------|
| 02/20/2012 |
| 11/29/2012 |
| 02/20/2012 |
| 11/29/2012 |
| 02/20/2012 |
| 11/29/2012 |
| 11/16/2011 |
| 02/20/2012 |
| 11/29/2012 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5493e/12)** demo

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
select convert(nvarchar(10), CREATED_TS, 101)
```

or

```
select format(cast(CREATED_TS as date), 'MM/dd/yyyy') -- MySQL 3.23 and above
```

Answer (score 0):

Date in SQL Server is by default in YYYY-MM-DD format. If you want to convert any column in SQL Server be it Date of Birth or Shipping Date, Manufacturing Date etc....to dd/mm/yyy format you can use the following method.

Firstly understand that formatting any column is applicable only in portraying of the output to the user and will not hold any value to how the data is stored. Which means that the data will be stored in the server in its original format but when the output is displayed you can control how it will be displayed.

To convert a column in dd/mm/yyyy format you can use the below:

Imagine there is a table called Employee_Details as below:

```
     ID     Dept  Salary   DOB
1   Akash   HR  30000   1989-02-25
2   Milind  Finance 45000   1975-12-15
3   Ananya  Admin   25000   1988-08-13
4   Girish  Finance 58000   1989-05-19
5   Ujwala  HR  28000   1997-04-26
6   Mahesh  Sales   60000   1982-11-15
7   Supriya Marketimg   80000   1979-09-30
8   Nidhi   Admin   25789   1980-03-02
9   Jai Sales   70000   1999-07-06
10  Aditya  Sales   56000   1980-02-28
```

I will covert the DOB column to display the results in an alias column in dd/mm/yyyy format

``````````````````````````````````````````````````````
Select ID,Name,Department,Salary,Convert(nvarchar,DOB,103) as DateofBirth from EMPLOYEE_DETAILS
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````[enter image description here][1]

Hope this will help


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCJFc.jpg
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Answer (score -1):

(Date today) ddmmyyyy.

ddmmyyyy
"Answer the receiver rendered in French format mm/dd/yyyy.
Note that the name here is slightly misleading -- the month and day numbers show leading zeros,
so that for example February 1 1996 is 01/02/96"

```
^ self printFormat: #(1 2 3 $/ 1 1 2)
```

Comment: in smalltalk ...

Comment: "in smalltalk"—and yet the question is tagged for SQL, specifically T-SQL as used in SQL Server.

Comment: Writing the month first is the format used in the United States (USA), so I don't understand this part of your answer: _rendered in French format mm/dd/yyyy_