# converting date to DD-MMM-YYYY format

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, date-formatting

I'm using following line of code in SQL:

```
REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),getdate(),106), ' ','-')
```

to convert given date to `MMM-DD-YYYY` format, this code is working perfectly fine if current date is more that 10th.

But I'm getting error when its tries to convert single digit date, e.g when I'm converting date `9 jan 2014`. It is converted to `Jan--9-2014`.

Which is actually wrong as its contain one extra `-`.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Why do you store the `datetime` as string at all?

Comment: Just in case, what if you use replace double spaces with single spaces before replacing spaces with dashes?

Comment: But [it is working fine for `9 jan 2014` here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/27927)?

Comment: showing correct date when executing.. select REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),getdate(),106), ' ','-') shows 08-Jan-2014 current date here..

Comment: except for question author expects month first, not day. And also wants day in one digit if it's in range 1-9

Comment: select REPLACE(cast(getDate() as varchar(11)), ' ','-')  returns Jan--8-2014 check if you are using cast or convert..

Comment: @user1455836 Yes, you are right. Sorry

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a particular date format ('dd-MMM-yyyy') in SELECT query SQL Server 2008 R2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202260/how-to-get-a-particular-date-format-dd-mmm-yyyy-in-select-query-sql-server-2)

Answer (score 2):

**CONVERT DATE IN dd-mmm-yyyy FORMAT (Eg. 01-Jun-2018)**

```
REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(11), DOB, 106),' ','-')  AS DOB
```

Answer (score 2):

*As of SQL Server 2012+*, you can use [`FORMAT(value, format [, culture ])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql)

Where the `format` param takes any valid [standard format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) or [custom formatting string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

**Example**:

```sql
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'dd-MMM-yyyy')
```

**Further Reading**:

- [How to convert DateTime to VarChar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74385/1366033)
- [How to convert date to a format `mm/dd/yyyy`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18568410/1366033)
- [sql server convert date to string MM/DD/YYYY](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11854775/1366033)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(11),getdate(),103)
```

see [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp) for more details

Answer (score -1):

Try This.

```
select REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,getdate(),107), ' ','-'), ',','')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select REPLACE(replace(cast(getDate() as varchar(11)), '  ', ' '), ' ','-')
```

returns correct result Jan-9-2014 on your fiddle

[here is the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/27934)

Comment: It still returns `Jan--9-2014`

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

```
select REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(cast(getDate() as varchar(11)),' ','{}'),'}{',''),'{}','-')
```

Output: `Jan-9-2014`

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/27937)</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

What about

```
select left(DATEname(m,getdate()),3)+'-'+  
cast(DAY(getdate()) as varchar)+'-'+ 
CAST(year(getdate()) as varchar)
```

?