# Change SQL date format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a column with this format `20150228` and I need to change it to `02/28/2015`. Is there any function in SQL to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Have you even *tried* `cast`ing or `convert`ing it to a date first?

Comment: possible duplicate of [sql server convert date to string MM/DD/YYYY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854775/sql-server-convert-date-to-string-mm-dd-yyyy)

Comment: What **datatype** is your column? If it's already a `DATE` or `DATETIME` - those **don't have any format!**; only when you cast it to a `varchar` is any *formatting* applied ....

Answer (score 3):

You can use this assuming the date is stored as a varchar:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),CONVERT(DATE,'20150228',112),101)
```

It returns:

02/28/2015

Answer (score 0):

Use `FORMAT` function:

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101)
```