# I need a SQL server query to convert date to Mon DD, YYYY HH:MM:SS AM/PM

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

I need a SQL server query to convert date to `Mon DD, YYYY HH:MM:SS AM/PM`

for e.g. the date is :-
`2016-11-21 16:58:57.797`

I need the SQL output as 
`Nov 21 2016  4:58:57 PM`

I tried --> `CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),GETDATE(),109)`
but it is displaying results like --> `Nov 21 2016  4:58:5`

Comment: Is is mysql or sql-server? It can't be both

Comment: Please tag with your RDBMS (product and version)!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11854877/68607

Answer (score 1):

Increase the length of VARCHAR in your statement like below

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),GETDATE(),109)
```

This is giving me result as `Nov 21 2016 12:55:31:390PM`

Hope this should work out for you.

Comment: But I don't want the milisseconds to come up

Answer (score 0):

For mysql you can do this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%b %d %Y %h:%i %p');
```

For ms sql you can do this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),GETDATE())
```

Reference:

- [MySQL DATE_FORMAT() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)
- [SQL Server CONVERT() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX` to get the left part of the string excluding the milliseconds part. Then concatenate the last AM/PM with that.

**Query**

```
declare @date as varchar(30) = convert(varchar(30),getdate(),109);
select substring(@date, 1, len(@date) - charindex(':', reverse(@date), 1)) 
       + ' ' + right(@date, 2) as [datetime];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
select FORMAT(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATETIME),'MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss tt') AS DateTimeAMPM
```