# I am looking to put a comma after two digits from right

Tags: sql

I am looking to put a comma after two digits from right. For example i have 250$ and in SQL I want the select to return 2,50$. Example2: 500$ should be 5.00$. For 1000$. It should be 10,00$. How can it be done in select. I have a column that holds those value in my SQL database.
Thanks you in advance for your help.
My column data type is bigint

Comment: Keep in mind Display value  vs stored value.  Don't store more than you have to.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854775/sql-server-convert-date-to-string-mm-dd-yyyy/11854877#11854877

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ironically, you can do this the same way in almost any database:

```
select cast( (col / 100.0) as decimal(20, 2))
```

Comment: Wow, Thanks million... your syntaxe resolved my issue..................

Comment: I was solving my issue in the way that was very complicated but here you gave me an easy answer i never thought about. Thanks Gordon Linoff