# How do i convert a date to mm/dd/yyyy in my where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have thousands of records that were added today but at different hours of the day, The only way I'm able to see them is if I do ORDER BY ADDdate DESC

However, i need to make an update statement where I want to update a particulr field using WHERE clause with the date

The problem is, since they were all entered at different times, how am i able to CAST/CONVERT this field so that I can only do something like....

Basically every added record has a AddDate field in datetime format, i want it converted to mm/dd/yyyy format.

```
Update SpecialField
SET SpecialField = NULL
Where ADDdate = '09/18/2017'
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql server convert date to string MM/DD/YYYY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854775/sql-server-convert-date-to-string-mm-dd-yyyy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use standard date formats.  I prefer YYYY-MM-DD, although SQL Server has a slight preference for YYYYMMDD.

Here are two ways:

```
Update SpecialField
    set SpecialField = NULL
    where ADDdate >= '2017-09-18' and ADDdate < '2017-09-19';
```

The the `>=` for the first value and `<` for the second.

or

```
Update SpecialField
    set SpecialField = NULL
    where cast(ADDdate as date) = '2017-09-18';
```

In both cases, SQL Server will use an index, so they are both reasonable ways of expressing the logic.

If you specifically want *today*'s date, then use `getdate()`, such as:

```
Update SpecialField
    set SpecialField = NULL
    where cast(ADDdate as date) = cast(getdate() as date);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to update all records where `ADDdate` is on 9/18/2017 (regardless of time), you could do something like this:

```
UPDATE SpecialField, SpecialField2
SET SpecialField = NULL
WHERE ADDdate > '09/18/2017' AND ADDdate < '09/19/2017'
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's a frequent requirement, you could simply not worry about typing dates.

```
where addDate >= cast(getdate() as date)
and addDate < dateadd(day, -1, cast(getdate() as date))
```

**Edit**

This has some similarities to Gordon's answer in that it uses `cast(getdate as date)`.  The difference is that he filters on a function result which tends to slow down performance.