# SQL procedure put today's date to the file name

Tags: sql, date, title

I am creating a procedure and trying to put output file name with today's date. Whenever I run it, I want to see that date with MMDDYYYY format. 
I have 2 output file, so their name will be AD_MMDDYYY and the other one is IM_MMDDYYYY

```
    IF la_dtc_population.COUNT > 0
   THEN
       IF pv_file_type IN ('ID.&sysdate', 'AD.&sysdate' )
```

What it will be, this doesn't work? Thanks

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql server convert date to string MM/DD/YYYY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854775/sql-server-convert-date-to-string-mm-dd-yyyy)

Answer (score 1):

This might not answer your question, but the following SQL will fill the variable `@date` with the current date in the format `mmddyyyy`, which you can then use to create the appropriate filenames:

```
declare @now    varchar(20) =
    convert(varchar(20), getdate(), 20);    -- Format 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'
declare @date   varchar(20) =
    substring(@now, 6, 2) + substring(@now, 9, 2) + substring(@now, 1, 4);
```

I think this should be pretty standard SQL (although I used MS-SQL/T-SQL to test it).