# converting a SQL server date time to mysql date time

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert DateTime to VarChar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74385/how-to-convert-datetime-to-varchar)

Example

How do you convert a SQL datetime (for example `08/14/2012 1:05:18 PM` ) to the mysql way ( that is Y-m-d H:i:s )?

Comment: [strtotime](http://strtotime.onlinephpfunctions.com/) and [date](http://date.onlinephpfunctions.com/)

Comment: Considering the vagueness of the question and the tags selected, this does not appear to be a direct duplicate.

Comment: "How to convert DateTime to VarChar" is not an exact duplicate. it's not even a close duplicate. So that statement goes to the closers! As to the vagueness of the question, I agree with RobB that it IS vague. I did not realize that when I was asking it though. I did not see it as SQL. This question is good cause it drew me nuts for 2 hours. It would help many people who take date & time information from two different fields from within SQL server and to simply insert it into a mysql date field. Not in a million years, I would have search it as DateTime to VarChar conversion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depends on where you are wanting to convert it.

To convert in your SQL directly:

```
convert(varchar(23), getdate(), 121)
```

PHP using the [date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) functions:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s ", strtotime("08/14/2012 1:05:18 PM"));
```

Comment: Right on the dot. date("Y-m-d H:i:s ", strtotime("08/14/2012 1:05:18 PM")); was all needed.

Answer (score 2):

Change the format of the date in PHP like so:

```
<?
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s ", strtotime("08/14/2012 1:05:18 PM"));
echo $date;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$var = "08/14/2012 1:05:18 PM";
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($var));
```