# SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 110) what is the meaning of 110 here?

Tags: sql, date, casting, getdate

When we convert or cast date in sql, see below sql code

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 110) AS [MM-DD-YYYY]
```

it works fine, I just want to know the meaning of 110 in above code. what it does actually, sometimes we use 102, 112 etc. what is the use of that number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert DateTime to VarChar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74385/how-to-convert-datetime-to-varchar)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That number indicates Date and Time Styles

You need to look at [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Here you can find the meaning of all these Date and Time Styles.

Styles with century (e.g. 100, 101 etc) means year will come in `yyyy` format. While styles without century (e.g. 1,7,10) means year will come in `yy` format.

You can also refer to [SQL Server Date Formats](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx). Here you can find all date formats with examples.

Answer (score 2):

When you convert expressions from one type to another, in many cases there will be a need within a stored procedure or other routine to convert data from a datetime type to a varchar type. The `Convert function` is used for such things. The `CONVERT()` function can be used to display date/time data in various formats.

**Syntax**

```
CONVERT(data_type(length), expression, style)
```

*Style* - style values for datetime or smalldatetime conversion to character data.  Add 100 to a style value to get a four-place year that includes the century (yyyy).

**Example 1**

take a style value 108 which defines the following format:

> hh:mm:ss

Now use the above style in the following query:

```
select convert(varchar(20),GETDATE(),108)
```

**Example 2**

we use the style value 107 which defines the following format:

> Mon dd, yy

Now use that style in the following query:

```
select convert(varchar(20),GETDATE(),107)
```

**Similarly**

```
style-106 for Day,Month,Year (26 Sep 2013)
style-6 for Day, Month, Year (26 Sep 13)
style-113 for Day,Month,Year, Timestamp (26 Sep 2013 14:11:53:300)
```

Answer (score 1):

`110` is the Style value for the date format.

[TSQL Date and Time Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

10 = mm-dd-yy
110 = mm-dd-yyyy

[SQL Server CONVERT() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp)