# Null Date returning invalid date

Tags: t-sql, case

Trying to change NULLs in a date field into blank results but it keeps returning a date. I'm doing it in a case when as i need to meet the following criteria:

```
CASE WHEN closed = 'y' THEN Date ELSE '' END
```

I've tried casting as varchar and other things it either throws a error or does nothing!

Comment: Are you really trying to return a character value?  As in, what is happening to the date that is returned - is it just being displayed or something else that is equivalent to a character value?

Comment: There is no such thing as a blank date.  You either have NULL or a date value.  Where did you try casting it as a varchar?

Comment: CONVERT, not cast, is probably your issue I'd guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert it to a varchar:

```
CASE WHEN closed = 'y' THEN LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, Date, 120), 10) ELSE '' END
```

See [How to convert DateTime to VarChar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74385/how-to-convert-datetime-to-varchar) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

A column in your result can only contain one type, it can't be both a date and a text field. You could convert your date to a string providing you no longer need it to be a date like so:

```
CASE WHEN closed = 'y' 
THEN CAST(Date AS VARCHAR) 
ELSE '' END
```