# Using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP result to insert in an INSERT INTO statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, timestamp

I was trying to execute the following query:

```
DECLARE @MyValue DATETIME
SET @MyValue = CAST((SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as DATETIME)
INSERT INTO Person (Gender,Name, JoinDate)
VALUES ('M','Alfred',@MyValue)
```

but SQL Server keeps throwing the following error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Insert_Current_Time, Line 8
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

I've already tried many other things, but none of them seemed to solve it. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Can you show the schema for table `Person`? If `JoinDate` is specified as a `DateTime`, it works properly for me.

Comment: This [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c841c/4) suggests you're not telling us everything we need to know.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
INSERT INTO Person (Gender,Name, JoinDate)
VALUES ('M','Alfred',getdate())
```

or this:

```
INSERT INTO Person (Gender,Name, JoinDate)
VALUES ('M','Alfred',current_timestamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP into your insert and dispense with the cast?
This works for me:

```
create table flar ( thetime datetime);
insert into flar values( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Comment: Nope. Already tried that, same mistake (Msg 241, Level 16, State 1)

Comment: I literally copied that from the sql server management studio window after running it. SQL server version 10.50. What is the data type of the destination column?

Answer (score 0):

Is **JoinDate** a string/varchar datatype? If so you need to cast it to a string instead of trying to store a datetime value in a string field.

Check this out: [How to convert DateTime to VarChar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74385/how-to-convert-datetime-to-varchar)

Comment: JoinDate is a datetime type

Comment: Odd, the only way I get a similar error in VS 2012 is to mix datatypes. As a DateTime column there was no problem, can you add your DDL for the table?

Comment: What do you mean with DDL? The problem is in the SQL Server layer, and not in the Visual Studio application

Comment: The DDL (Data Definition Language) is the code that is used to build the table in SQL ex: [CREATE STATEMENT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language#CREATE_statements) what I'm looking for are the datatypes of your columns as it looks like they are causing the problem based on a few results found in this thread.