# SQL Server Query: Convert to dd/mm/yyyy from datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I'm querying a max datetime to bring in the most recent record from another table surrounding a common ID coloumn. I would like to however format this datetime in the standard UK dd/mm/yyyy format. How would I do so? I just cant seem to get this...

Here is my code:

```
    (SELECT TOP 1 MemberPayments.CoverFinishDay
FROM
    Members LEFT JOIN MemberPayments
        ON Members.MemberID = MemberPayments.MemberID
        AND CoverFinishDay = (
            SELECT MAX(CoverFinishDay)
            FROM MemberPayments
            WHERE Members.MemberID = MemberPayments.MemberID
        ))
```

CoverFinishDay is stored in standard american datetime. currently the query works, just in the wrong format. I need the output in dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: Why do you need it in text format in the database? Isn't that something for your presentation layer?

Comment: Which DBMS you are using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert DateTime to VarChar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74385/how-to-convert-datetime-to-varchar)

Comment: this is a direct database query that will be presented in a presentation layer. Difficult to explain, in-house Rapid development enviroment. SO the resultant value will exist in a coloumn alongside other values (member name, ID no etc...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 105)
```

This is for SQL Sever

Comment: so would I encapsulate my entire query within the GETDATE()?

Comment: No. It would be like this.. SELECT TOP 1 CONVERT(VARCHAR,MemberPayments.CoverFinishDay,105)....

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 you can convert any date using `FORMAT` function. In your case you can do like this:

```
SELECT FORMAT (MemberPayments.CoverFinishDay, 'd', 'en-GB')
```

For mor info you can access the page: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505(v=sql.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)