# convert datetime to varchar(50)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Need help in converting datetime to varchar as in given format

```
2015-01-04 16:07:37.000"
```

to

```
01/04/2015 16:07PM
```

Here is what tried:

```
convert(varchar(20),datetime,103)+ ' '+convert(varchar(20),datetime,108)+ ' ' +right(convert(varchar(30),datetime,109),2)
```

Comment: I had tried "convert(varchar(20),datetime,103)+ ' '+convert(varchar(20),datetime,108)+
 ' ' +right(convert(varchar(30),datetime,109),2)"

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: You may use this for date time conversion : http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/ AND http://stackoverflow.com/a/19537658/4609016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will work in `sqlserver` [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4e26e/1) regarding this Demo

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 103) 
+' '+ CONVERT(varchar(15),CAST(getdate() AS TIME),100)
```

Comment: @user3244104 it ll show exact output , u need to change according to ur variable from getdate() to urs datetime ...

Answer (score 1):

This will get your string from current datetime in the format `06/22/15  1:46:07 PM`.

```
 SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), GETDATE(), 22)
```

Try using Format

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'g')
```

which will get `6/22/2015 1:57 PM`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always build it yourself using DATEPART...

```
SELECT
    RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(nvarchar(max), DATEPART(m, Date_Field)), 2) + '/' + 
    RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(nvarchar(max), DATEPART(d, Date_Field)), 2) + '/' + 
    CONVERT(nvarchar(max), DATEPART(yyyy, Date_Field))  + ' ' + 
    RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(nvarchar(max), DATEPART(hour, Date_Field)), 2) + ':' + 
    RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(nvarchar(max), DATEPART(minute, Date_Field)), 2) + 
    RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), Date_Field, 9), 2)
```

Then you can use custom delimiters between the date and times, add seconds (or milliseconds, etc.) as you need.  Wrap it in a UDF if you find the need to use it a lot.