# MSSQL date to php

Tags: php, sql-server, date, datetime

I have googled extensively, seen various stackoverflow solutions, but none work here. Not sure why. Help would be great!

The date is stored in a smalldatetime field in MSSQL. The value of this is seen as "2015-11-27 00:00:00". This seems the same format as a date in mySQL. The example below works if the value is pasted in, but not the value from the recordset.

```
    //gives correct result, 11/27/2015
    $TravDate = date("m/d/Y", strtotime("2015-11-27 00:00:00"));

    //gives wrong result, 12/31/1969
    $TravDate = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($obj->TravDate));
```

Comment: print_r on $obj->TravDate ?

Comment: and try to echo its type and submit your answer here for us to see

Comment: do the following and edit into you question: var_dump($obj->TravDate);

Comment: Sorry, first time use print_r and not sure how to echo the type. Tried below and nothing appeared, as also straight echo of $obj->TravDate

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r ($obj->TravDate);
        echo '</pre>';

Comment: That's probably your problem, then. TravDate is empty...

Comment: Tried echo "<br>TravDateDump=".var_dump($obj->TravDate); and this gave no value for the field. All other non-date database fields gave values. In Studio Express the value can be seen as 2015-11-27 00:00:00. So problem is definitely extracting this value into PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try

```
  $datetime = new DateTime( $obj->travdate); //create datetime object with received data
    $reform = $datetime->format('Y M d');   //do reformat as required
```

Refer to http://af-design.com/blog/2010/03/13/microsoft-sql-server-driver-for-php-returns-datetime-object/

Comment: That is msql. Am using sqlsrv for MSSQL.

Comment: Thanks that worked! Did not expect anything for reason you gave, but to my surprise it gave "reform=2015 Aug 28" which is correct.

Comment: Sorry, update. That gave today's date, not 11/27/2015, so seems there is a problem with getting a value here.

Comment: It acts like it is blank. But all other values gave correct values using $obj->xxx, and in Studio Express I see the value "2015-11-27 00:00:00". I have just run the same recordset in ASP and it gave the correct value. So why is $obj -->travdate null if $obj --> is working for other fields and there IS a non-null value in the database?

Comment: My answer is updated with a link. Check there, return date time as string, configuration.

Comment: This link looks like it explains why there is a problem, and provides solutions. I have not tried, as I used the solution below (converting the field to a string in the SQL query), but assuming these solutions work I will mark as solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure the *$obj->TravDate* serialized to string is correct, probably solved value is not correct. Try firstly stringify and after use strtotime() function.

Comment: Sorry, newbie here. Field values were taken from database, not serialized from a form. Tried the following code, gave error:-

            'code'
            $TravDate=$obj->TravDate;
            $TravDate=(string)$TravDate;
            $TravDate = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($TravDate));

Answer (score 0):

Solution found. I gave up using PHP method above: it worked for all other variables in the recordset except the date field TravDate, which is *not* null.

Solution involved changing the SQL query by converting the date field as follows:-
CONVERT(varchar(10), TravDate, 20) AS TravDate  (php echo giving 11/27/2015).
This solution found in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74385/how-to-convert-datetime-to-varchar).