# converting date to string

Tags: sql, datetime

I have a table with expdate column which contains dates. Dates are in different formats i.e. 01-Apr-17 12:00:00 AM , 02/2017, 3/1/2017 12:00:00 AM.. 
I want to extract date from this table in mm/yy format..

Comment: Dates have no format. Store them as `datetime` instead of `varchar`. Which rdbms are you using at all?

Comment: This is not a problem for SQL, in my opinion. Extract the dates and format them in a more appropriate language (your choice). PHP has e.g. `strtotime()` and `date()` for that purpose.

Comment: Please provide the code and let us know which part is problematic. As it stands now the question is hard to answer.

Comment: case when len(expirydate)=21 then  cast(month(expirydate) as varchar)+'/'+cast(right(year(@date),2) as varchar) else cast(LEFT(substring(@date, patindex('%[^0]%',@date), 10), CHARINDEX('/', substring(@date, patindex('%[^0]%',@date), 10), 0)-1) as varchar)+'/'+cast(right(@date,2) as varchar) end as 'date'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert DateTime to VarChar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74385/how-to-convert-datetime-to-varchar)

Comment: did you tried this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?