# C# ListView Shows time from Datetime after converted to DATE in SQL

Tags: c#, sql

Why does C# still get the time from SQL if stored procedure only gets the date from a column:

```
CONVERT (DATE,RecordAdded, 103) as DateCaptured
```

Result:

[image: Result in Listview]

I am selecting the date from a datetime column in SQL, then dumping it into a Listview. But I only want the date to display in the listview.

```
ListViewItem FeedbackTable = new ListViewItem(FeedbackReader["DateCaptured"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.ToString()` for formatting your DateTime as string. Watch this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information. In your case this should work:

```
ListViewItem FeedbackTable = new ListViewItem(FeedbackReader["DateCaptured"].ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

Notice you maybe need to convert `Convert.ToDateTime(FeedbackReader["DateCaptured"]);`

UPDATE:

If you get the field as Date from your Database, it will be DateTime in C#. And DateTime always contains a Time Component. So what you can do is to modify the result from your StoredProcedure. How you can achieve this is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74385/how-to-convert-datetime-to-varchar).

Change the return Type of your StoredProcedure to string, so you can correctly show the information in your ListView:

```
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @myDateTime, 120), 10);
```

Comment: I have tried adding "yyy-MM-dd" as sugested, but then I get this error: "No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments"

Comment: Using "ListViewItem FeedbackTable = new ListViewItem(Convert.ToDateTime(FeedbackReader["DateCaptured"].ToString()));" gives me this error: " Argument1: connot convert from 'System.DateTime' to 'String' "

Comment: If your Argument expects a DateTime you cannot give it a string. A DateTime always got the Time Component. Use the ToString where you print your result on Konsole, Form, Report etc.

Comment: I get my info from stored procedure in SQL. Then I use a Reader to read the returning results and dump it in the listview. Not sure where or how to make a change so that only the time shows.

Comment: @ExpressDude See my Update. Changing your SQL is the solution. Hope you are able to modify your statement/procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Because a DateTime is a DateTime, containing both Date and Time part.
And DateTime.ToString() is implementented so it display also the Time part (which is 00:00, as result of your query)

Use the appropriate formatting for DateTime: e.g

```
myDateTime.ToString("d"); //short date pattern
```

or

```
myDateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); // your custom display string
```

Now you have to create a ListViewItem with your correct date format; try this:

```
ListViewItem FeedbackTable = new ListViewItem(Convert.ToDateTime(FeedbackReader["DateCaptured"]).ToString("d"));
```

i.e., first you convert `FeedbackReader["DateCaptured"])` (which is defined as `object`) to a DateTime, then apply the correct formatting (with `ToString("d");`) and then create your listviewItem with the desired string

Comment: Are you referring to when one submit the date with the DateTime picker to SQL?

Comment: No, i mean that FeedbackReader["DateCaptured"] returns a DateTime, with year, month, day, hour, minute, second and fraction of second. In your case, the time part is 00:00.0000. This does not mean that DateTime.ToString() doesn't display the time part

Comment: ok I understand. But I am still stuck in only getting the date to display in the listview.

Answer (score 0):

I have found my solution. Logic actually, but so I learn...

I changed in SQL procedure this:

```
CONVERT (DATE,RecordAdded, 103) as DateCaptured,
```

To:

```
CONVERT (VARCHAR(10),RecordAdded, 103) as DateCaptured,
```

Now SQL converts it to a string after formatting it, giving me the result I want.

[The Result I wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhr3v.jpg)

Comment: As you say, this works, but my advice is not to use this pattern: with the query you should get the data you need (in this case, a date), and with the code you should format your date according to your needs. Keep things separated: retrieve data from display them