# How to convert DateTime to VarChar with specific format, without using string functions?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012, sybase, datetime-format

I wanna convert DateTime to VarChar.

it seams it so dublicated question

but wait a minute.

the next link is awesome:

[How to convert DateTime to VarChar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74385/how-to-convert-datetime-to-varchar)

but it is not effect to my question.

my output is neer to format 101

```
CONVERT(varchar(10), [MyDateTimecolumn], 101)
```

**Output:**

```
04/21/2000
```

I Wanna the output without zero in month

**Requested Output**

```
4/21/2000
```

is it applicable, without using any string function (like substring, replace, ... etc) ?

**Updated** The requested code is should be runnable on `SQLServer2005`, `SQLServer2012` & `Sybase`

Comment: Better way to handle this at UI side

Comment: @jelliaes it seams i was dreaming while request M/D/YYYY without using string functions, thanks all :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL 2012 or higher you can achieve it using the `FORMAT` function native to SQL.

```
FORMAT(YourDate, 'M/dd/yyyy')
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i waana code is running on SQLServer 2008, SQLServer2012 & Sybase, I edited the tags.