# T-SQL: DateTme Column varchar cast that may contain '1753-01-01' to empty string

Tags: t-sql, datetime, type-conversion, ssms, sql-server-2014

Task: convert a `DateTme` column (cast as varchar) that may contain `1753-01-01` to an empty string.

What is the most efficient way to do this in T-SQL?

For example, if I use:

```
SELECT 
    LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DateCol1, 120), 10) 
FROM
    ourDatabase.dbo.ourTable
```

How can I efficiently change any row containing '1753-01-01' to an empty string?

**NOTE:** it appears the value '1753-01-01' really does appear in the database table; it sometimes is returned where there are nulls. One can even do a datepart yy and get 1753, so it is NOT ‘null’ in the ordinary sense.

Please see also:
[What is the significance of 1/1/1753 in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310569/what-is-the-significance-of-1-1-1753-in-sql-server) 
for background on this specific date.

Also, please see: {general discussion of Datetime to varchar conversion}:

[How to convert DateTime to VarChar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74385/how-to-convert-datetime-to-varchar)

This is for Microsoft SQL Server 2014  using SSMS 14.0.17

Comment: could you not update the table, converting those dates to your empty string, so that your selects don't have to do any conversion?

Comment: That's a good thought, but it is not allowed.

Comment: Aside: From [`VarChar(n)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): "When _n_ is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. When _n_ is not specified when using the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30." The best practice is to _always_ specify a length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `replace()`.

```
SELECT replace(left(convert(varchar, datecol1, 120), 10), '1753-01-01', '')
       FROM ourtable;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=fe744958643cb02435ba7c89ba9cad72)

Comment: Just what the 'doctor' ordered {I happen to be a PhD}.  I'd spell replace with a capital 'R' but that's not important.  (-: