# ERROR: varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in error out-of-range value

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, time

I get this error message when I run the below query. Do you have any idea how I can solve this error?

> varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in error out-of-range value

I have been messing around with "convert" and "cast" but to date I have not had any success with this.

I tried this:

```
CONVERT(nvarchar, XDateUpdated, 103) AS XDateUpdated
```

This is what the date / time looks like in my table: 7/31/2019 3:32:23,000 AM

```
SELECT TOP <Max_Message_Count> 
    XDateInserted, XUserInserted, XDateUpdated, XUserUpdated, ApprovalState, 
    PersonnelNumber
FROM 
    Person
```

I think the problem is because no match can be made with not the datetime and timestamp.

EDIT: I looked closer at the information in my tabel. This is de date/time what my database generates:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1sXk.png)

Excuse me for the incorrect information

Comment: Always specify the length, `VARCHAR(n)`

Comment: what is the datatype of column in your table which holds this date.

Comment: as Sami said, Always specify the length, VARCHAR(n).This could be useful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74385/how-to-convert-datetime-to-varchar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you seem to want to convert a string to a *datetime* value.  Not the other way around.

Second, SQL Server is pretty good about converting date/time values.  But commas do confuse it.

So, I think this does what you want:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, REPLACE(XDateUpdated, ',', '.')) AS XDateUpdated
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find this link for the details about `datetime` field in sql server [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

`,` is not accepted in any datetime format as per the document. You may replace `,` with `.` to convert your string into valid datetime format.

```
declare @myrec nvarchar(max)
set @myrec = '7/31/2019 13:32:23,000 PM'

select CONVERT(DATETIME, REPLACE(@myrec, ',', '.')) AS MyDate
```