# Datetime conversion error - The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I'm getting the conversion error when converting below value.`

```
select CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(' September 2, 2019 14:29:46', 21), 101)
```

but I can convert the below value without an error

```
select CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(' August 31, 2019 11:43:44', 21), 101)
```

It really thankful if someone can help.

Comment: If at all possible don't pass around datetime values as string at all. If you "have" to do so, please consider [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). It's standard, it's fixed length, and it's unambiguous.

Comment: Actually, a combination of Damien's comment with Larnu's and iamdave's answers should give you the solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74385/how-to-convert-datetime-to-varchar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't the style `101`, it's the style `100` (`101` is `MM/dd/yyyy`). You also have a leading `' '` that you should to remove:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,STUFF(' September 2, 2019 14:29:46',1,1,''),100);
```

Note, as well, that this'll fail if you aren't using an English derived language [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fb8505ced9913776b56f092fdf657bce). Passing the name if a month for a date is one of the worst ways to pass a date/time value, as if you change language it will no longer work.

Even though an unambiguous format (`yyyyMMdd` or `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.sss`) is best, if you are going to use an ambiguous one at least use one that doesn't provide the name of the month and only uses numerical characters to provide the date.

Comment: The leading space does not *need* to be explicitly removed.

Comment: @Larnu Thank you very much friend for your help. This values were scrape from a site. that's why it getting a the name of the month.

Answer (score 2):

The `left(...,21)` for both your values results in the following:

```
LEFT(' September 2, 2019 14:29:46', 21) -> September 2, 2019 14
LEFT(' August 31, 2019 11:43:44', 21)   -> August 31, 2019 11:4
```

Hopefully from this you can see why your `left` conversion logic is flawed and why it is failing.

As your values are already in a recognised date value format, you don't actually need to modify them at all:

```
select CONVERT(datetime, ' September 2, 2019 14:29:46', 100)
      ,CONVERT(datetime, ' August 31, 2019 11:43:44', 100)
```

returns:

```
2019-09-02 14:29:46.000
2019-08-31 11:43:44.000
```

Comment: But you do want to use the `style` attribute, and you might also considering setting the language explicitly because the language that SQL Server is using in each session is the default language of the login unless specified otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

If want to use OP approach, you should subtract your length of string with the time part, as time part is always fixed while length of month name is almost vary every month.

```
    DECLARE @ReportStartDate varchar(30) = 'September 2, 2019 14:29:46'
    select  convert ( datetime, left( @ReportStartDate, len(@ReportStartDate) - 9), 101)
```

Comment: Not mine, but at a guess because it replicated iamdave's answer (though it has since changed); but was posted 10 minutes later. Maybe the use of the `MAX` datatype to store a date, or possibly because the style code wasn't corrected (as the above uses `101` which is for `MM/dd/yyyy`), so *could* result in unexpected behaviour.

Comment: hope now it is different... ;)

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server is actually pretty good at picking out date formats when there is no conversion specifier.  Because your dates have month names, this is quite safe with your strings.

So, you can just do:

```
select convert(datetime, ' September 2, 2019 14:29:46'),
       convert(datetime, ' August 31, 2019 11:43:44')
```

Personally, I would use `TRY_CONVERT()` instead:

```
select try_convert(datetime, ' September 2, 2019 14:29:46'),
       try_convert(datetime, ' August 31, 2019 11:43:44')
```