# SQL Server conversion error when using IIF on datetime field to output a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, date, t-sql

I have the following select statement:

```
SELECT IIF(DateFirstSeen IS NOT NULL, DateFirstSeen, 'Not Seen') as [Date First Seen]
```

But when I run this, I get the error:

```
Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type
```

Can anybody help with this?

Comment: convert `DateFirstSeen` to string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert DateTime to VarChar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74385/how-to-convert-datetime-to-varchar)

Comment: As per Demo's comment; IIF expects the second and third parameters to be the same type, if they're not one has to be converted to the other. In your case the IIF sees the SMALL DATETIME parameter, assumes that's the data type you want to return, then encounters the string, which can't be converted to a SMALLDATETIME.  So, if you want the IIF to return a string, give it two strings... To do that, convert the DateFirstSeen value to a string...

Comment: No, the conversion is simple enough, it's the IIF that is causing the problems, as pointed out below, both branches of IIF() must return the same datatype

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both branches of `IIF()` must return the same datatype, while you are mixing a date and a string.

Consider converting the date to string first, for example:

```
 COALESCE(CONVERT(varchar, DateFirstSeen, 23), 'Not Seen')
```

Note that, when dealing with `null`s, `COALESCE()` shortens the logic compared to `IIF()`.

Comment: You could also use the ISNULL function here :)

Comment: @CR7SMS: yes. I like `COALESCE()` better, because it's standard SQL - so most databases support it.

Answer (score 2):

The `IIF()` returns a single value.  But there are competing types.  Which type to use?  SQL standard emphasize that the most *restrictive* type is returned, not the most general.

To represent `'Not Seen'` you need a string.  You should use `convert()` or `format()` with the appropriate specification:

```
SELECT COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), DateFirstSeen, 120), 'Not Seen')
```

Or, learn to live with and love `NULL`s.