# Common MySQL fields and their appropriate data types

Tags: mysql, database, types

I am setting up a very small MySQL database that stores, first name, last name, email and phone number and am struggling to find the 'perfect' datatype for each field. I know there is no such thing as a perfect answer, but there must be some sort of common convention for commonly used fields such as these. For instance, I have determined that an unformatted US phone number is too big to be stored as an unsigned int, it must be at least a bigint.

Because I am sure other people would probably find this useful, I dont want to restrict my question to just the fields I mentioned above.

What datatypes are appropriate for common database fields? Fields like phone number, email and address?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Someone's going to post a much better answer than this, but just wanted to make the point that personally I would never store a phone number in any kind of integer field, mainly because:

1. You don't need to do any kind of arithmetic with it, and
2. Sooner or later someone's going to try to (do something like) put brackets around their area code.

In general though, I seem to almost exclusively use:

- INT(11) for anything that is either an ID or references another ID
- DATETIME for time stamps
- VARCHAR(255) for anything guaranteed to be under 255 characters (page titles, names, etc)
- TEXT for pretty much everything else.

Of course there are exceptions, but I find that covers most eventualities.

Comment: Also, integers only support up to value of 2 billion.  That's 2,000,000,000.  Which really isn't enough space when you want to store international phone numbers, complete with country code.  I don't even see how you could find enough space to store a number like 655-405-4055 (6,554,054,055)

Comment: Plus it's just wrong. Someone much wiser than me told me when I was starting out that (with databasing) just because something looks like a number doesn't mean it is or should be treated as such...

Comment: Blindly using varchar(255) is a bad idea.  At least apply some basic effort to guess the length.

Comment: @Morgan Tocker: it's the best practice, anything below 255 chars will take the same space.

Comment: @Raveren: This is storage engine specific - and storage is not the only cost.  Sorting data and temporary tables (memory engine) will use the fixed amount.

Comment: @da4id: so a phone **number** just looks like number ?

Comment: A phone number actually **is** a number, but only in textual understanding. 0004194821947 results in the same integer *number* as 004194821947 does, but it's absolutely not treated the same way in call routing mechanisms.

Comment: And, I think BIT for boolean values -  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-field-literals.html

Comment: FWIW `VARCHAR(255)` is "best practice" because `< MySQL 5.0.3` the limit on `VARCHAR` was `255`. That's now changed and I wouldn't use the term "best practice" here. `VARCHAR` can hold 65,535 bytes. I've also seen titles longer that 255 bytes. Here's one for example: https://np.reddit.com/r/confession/comments/6q7ttt/wehn_i_wsa_doing_this_allugh_als_p_apit_you_cant/

Comment: I know this is already old, but why use `INT(11)` for your ID? Why 11?

Comment: You may need to search against mobile numbers....

Answer (score 55):

Here are some common datatypes I use (I am not much of a pro though):

```
| Column           | Data type     | Note
| ---------------- | ------------- | -------------------------------------
| id               | INTEGER       | AUTO_INCREMENT, UNSIGNED                                                          |  
| uuid             | CHAR(36)      | or CHAR(16) binary                                                                |  
| title            | VARCHAR(255)  |                                                                                   |  
| full name        | VARCHAR(70)   |                                                                                   |  
| gender           | TINYINT       | UNSIGNED                                                                          |  
| description      | TINYTEXT      | often may not be enough, use TEXT 
                                     instead          
| post body        | TEXT          |                                                                                   |  
| email            | VARCHAR(255)  |                                                                                   |  
| url              | VARCHAR(2083) | MySQL version < 5.0.3 - use TEXT                                                  |  
| salt             | CHAR(x)       | randomly generated string, usually of 
                                     fixed length (x)    
| digest (md5)     | CHAR(32)      |                                                                                   |  
| phone number     | VARCHAR(20)   |                                                                                   |  
| US zip code      | CHAR(5)       | Use CHAR(10) if you store extended 
                                     codes      
| US/Canada p.code | CHAR(6)       |                                                                                   |  
| file path        | VARCHAR(255)  |                                                                                   |  
| 5-star rating    | DECIMAL(3,2)  | UNSIGNED                                                                          |  
| price            | DECIMAL(10,2) | UNSIGNED                                                                          |  
| date (creation)  | DATE/DATETIME | usually displayed as initial date of 
                                     a post                                       |  
| date (tracking)  | TIMESTAMP     | can be used for tracking changes in a 
                                     post                                        |  
| tags, categories | TINYTEXT      | comma separated values *                                                          |  
| status           | TINYINT(1)    | 1 – published, 0 – unpublished, … You 
                                     can also use ENUM for human-readable 
                                     values
| json data        | JSON          | or LONGTEXT
```

Comment: @yentsun - Emails are actually only 254; read the [comments to the question Neil McGuigan posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199190/what-is-the-optimal-length-for-an-email-address-in-a-database#1199238)

Comment: gender is not meant to be boolean any more

Comment: @MohammedShareefC and its not, its TINYINT!

Comment: @yentsun Surely it should now be INT instead ;)

Answer (score 16):

In my experience, first name/last name fields should be at least 48 characters -- there are names from some countries such as Malaysia or India that are very long in their full form.

Phone numbers and postcodes you should **always** treat as text, not numbers. The normal reason given is that there are postcodes that begin with 0, and in some countries, phone numbers can also begin with 0. But the real reason is that they aren't *numbers* -- they're *identifiers* that happen to be made up of numerical digits (and that's ignoring countries like Canada that have letters in their postcodes). So store them in a text field.

In MySQL you can use VARCHAR fields for this type of information. Whilst it sounds lazy, it means you don't have to be too concerned about the right minimum size.

Comment: To further support your comment on postal codes, in countries such as the UK or Canada, postal codes are alphanumeric.

Comment: You may need to be concerned about the right minimum size
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262238/are-there-disadvantages-to-using-a-generic-varchar255-for-all-text-based-field#comment17169031_262476

Comment: @iamrohitbanga Whilst you are correct for well-defined data, for names `VARCHAR(255)` makes sense.

Answer (score 9):

Since you're going to be dealing with data of a variable length (names, email addresses), then you'd be wanting to use VARCHAR. The amount of space taken up by a VARCHAR field is `[field length]` + 1 bytes, up to max length 255, so I wouldn't worry too much about trying to find a perfect size. Take a look at what you'd imagine might be the longest length might be, then double it and set that as your VARCHAR limit. That said...:

I generally set email fields to be VARCHAR(100) - i haven't come up with a problem from that yet. Names I set to VARCHAR(50).

As the others have said, phone numbers and zip/postal codes are not actually numeric values, they're strings containing the digits 0-9 (and sometimes more!), and therefore you should treat them as a string. VARCHAR(20) should be well sufficient.

Note that if you were to store phone numbers as integers, many systems will assume that a number starting with 0 is an octal (base 8) number! Therefore, the perfectly valid phone number "0731602412" would get put into your database as the decimal number "124192010"!!

Answer (score 5):

#### Any Table ID

Use: `INT(11)`.

[MySQL indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html) will be able to parse through an int list fastest.

#### Anything Security

Use: `BINARY(x)`, or `BLOB(x)`.

You can store security tokens, etc., as hex directly in BINARY(x) or BLOB(x).  To retrieve from `binary`-type, use `SELECT HEX(field)...` or `SELECT ...  WHERE field = UNHEX("ABCD....")`.

#### Anything Date

Use: `DATETIME`, `DATE`, or `TIME`.

Always use `DATETIME` if you need to store both date and time (instead of a pair of fields), as a `DATETIME` indexing is more amenable to date-comparisons in MySQL.

#### Anything True-False

Use: `BIT(1)` (MySQL 8-only.)  Otherwise, use `BOOLEAN(1)`.

`BOOLEAN` is actually just an alias of `TINYINT(1)`, which actually stores 0 to 255 (not exactly a true/false, is it?).

#### Anything You Want to call `SUM()`, `MAX()`, or similar functions on

Use: `INT(11)`.

VARCHAR or other types of fields won't work with the `SUM()`, etc., functions.

#### Anything Over 1,000 Characters

Use: TEXT.

Max limit is 65,535.

#### Anything Over 65,535 Characters

Use: MEDIUMTEXT.

Max limit is 16,777,215.

#### Anything Over 16,777,215 Characters

Use: LONGTEXT.

Max limit is 4,294,967,295.

#### FirstName, LastName

Use : `VARCHAR(255)`.

UTF-8 characters can take up three characters per visible character, and some cultures do not distinguish firstname and lastname.  Additionally, cultures may have disagreements about which name is *first* and which name is *last*.  You should name these fields `Person.GivenName` and `Person.FamilyName`.

#### Email Address

Use : `VARCHAR(256)`.

The definition of an e-mail path is set in [RFC821](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc821) in 1982.  The maximum limit of an e-mail was set by [RFC2821](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2821) in 2001, and these limits were kept unchanged by [RFC5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) in 2008.  (See the section: 4.5.3.1.  Size Limits and Minimums.)  [RFC3696](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3696), published 2004, mistakenly cites the email address limit as `320` characters, but this was an "info-only" RFC that explicitly "defines no standards" according to its intro, so disregard it.

#### Phone

Use: `VARCHAR(255)`.

You never know when the phone number will be in the form of "1800...", or "1-800", or "1-(800)", or if it will end with "ext. 42", or "ask for susan".

#### ZipCode

Use: `VARCHAR(10)`.

You'll get data like `12345` or `12345-6789`.  Use validation to cleanse this input.

#### URL

Use: `VARCHAR(2000)`.

Official standards support URL's much longer than this, but few modern browsers support URL's over 2,000 characters.  See [this SO answer: What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/417184/2430549)

#### Price

Use: `DECIMAL(11,2)`.

It goes up to 11.

Answer (score 1):

I am doing about the same thing, and here's what I did.

I used separate tables for name, address, email, and numbers, each with a NameID column that is a foreign key on everything except the Name table, on which it is the primary clustered key.  I used MainName and FirstName instead of LastName and FirstName to allow for business entries as well as personal entries, but you may not have a need for that.

The NameID column gets to be a smallint in all the tables because I'm fairly certain I won't make more than 32000 entries.  Almost everything else is varchar(n) ranging from 20 to 200, depending on what you wanna store (Birthdays, comments, emails, really long names).  That is really dependent on what kind of stuff you're storing.

The Numbers table is where I deviate from that.  I set it up to have five columns labeled NameID, Phone#, CountryCode, Extension, and PhoneType.  I already discussed NameID.  Phone# is varchar(12) with a check constraint looking something like this:  CHECK (Phone# like '[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]').  This ensures that only what I want makes it into the database and the data stays very consistent.  The extension and country codes I called nullable smallints, but those could be varchar if you wanted to.  PhoneType is varchar(20) and is not nullable.

Hope this helps!