# MySQL 5.1.41 leading zero is deleted

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database where I want to store phone numbers among other things.

The fieldtype is INT(10)

When I try to insert a number starting with a 0, like 0504042858 it's stored like 504042858. This only happens with phone numbers with leading zeros. When the number start with any other number, it's stored correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably store phone numbers as a `varchar`. Phone numbers are only numeric by accident.

You may also be interested in checking out the following Stack Overflow posts:

- [What datatype should be used for storing phone numbers in SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75105/what-datatype-should-be-used-for-storing-phone-numbers-in-sql-server-2005)
- [Common MySQL fields and their appropriate data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354763/common-mysql-fields-and-their-appropriate-data-types)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your quick response. I was wondering if storing a number as a string isn't bad practice. Also why would MySQL delete my 0 without me asking it?

Comment: It is not deleting it. 0504 is 504 in numeric terms... In addition, I would say that storing them as an `varchar` is in fact the good practice.

Comment: because integers doesn't have leading zeroes, 01, 0001 and 1 is still the same number , 1.

Comment: Thank you everybody for your answers, I changed the fieldtype to varchar(10) yet still my zeroes are deleted.

EDIT: emptied cache and suddenly works now, thanks everybody!

Answer (score 2):

You can give length **INT(11)** with attribute value **UNSIGNED_ZEROFILL**. it will fill all 11 digits and if any digit length is less than 11, it will add zero itself before the value. 
This might solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

it is removing the leading zero because mathematically they are the same and removing the leading zero is a quick storage optimization. In addition it also makes the numbers easier to read imagine a number padded with several leading zeros in a column of several hundred numbers.

I agree with Daniel change your column to a varchar.