# Not have a minimum MySQL INT Value

Tags: mysql

When I add a number beginning with 0 into my MySQL database, it automatically gets converted to a single digit. These are mobile numbers, so I need to keep it starting with 0.

Answer (score 3):

Store phone numbers as strings, not integers. (related: [Common MySQL fields and their appropriate data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354763/common-mysql-fields-and-their-appropriate-data-types) )

Answer (score 1):

Try storing the numbers as varchars instead. When you retreive them from the database you could cast them using (int) if needed.