# Whats the size of an SQL Int(N)?

Tags: sql, integer, size, int

Simple question. I have tried searching on Google and after about 6 searches, I figured it would be faster here.

How big is an int in SQL?

```
-- table creation statement.
intcolumn INT(N) NOT NULL,
-- more table creation statement.
```

How big is that `INT(N)` element? What's its range? Is it 2^N or is it N Bytes long? (2 ^ 8N)? Or even something else I have no idea about?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It depends on the database.  MySQL has an [extension](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html) where INT(N) means an INT with a **display width** of 4 decimal digits. This information is maintained in the metadata.

The INT itself is still 4 bytes, and values 10000 and greater can be stored (and probably displayed, but this depends how the application uses the result set).

Comment: Note this quite different from a type like VARCHAR(n), where n in that case is the max allowed stored chars.  See {http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634104/what-is-the-size-of-column-of-int11-in-mysql-in-bytes, http://stackoverflow.com/a/1262249/1357094}