# MySQL MyISAM - not able to add a new column to table

Tags: mysql, myisam, alter-table

I have the following table:

```
mysql> show create table keyword_links\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: keyword_links
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `keyword_links` (
  `keyword_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `keyword` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `link` tinytext,
  `weight` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `class_id` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `category_id` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`keyword_id`),
  KEY `class_id` (`class_id`),
  KEY `category_id` (`category_id`),
  KEY `idx_keyword` (`keyword`(333))
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5082 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

to which I am trying to add a new column, which is failing:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE keyword_links ADD COLUMN list_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
ERROR 1170 (42000): BLOB/TEXT column 'keyword' used in key specification without a key length
```

The index on `keyword` column does have a key length of 333, so why is it failing and how to fix it?

**UPDATE**

I tried reducing the size of the index on the `keyword` column from 333 to 255 and now I am able to add the new column successfully:

```
ALTER TABLE keyword_links DROP INDEX idx_keyword;
CREATE INDEX index_keyword ON keyword_links (keyword(255));
ALTER TABLE keyword_links ADD COLUMN list_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

But I would still like to know what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of myisam's index's length limit of 1000 bytes ([see this link](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb))

Please note that this is all about bytes, and that a character might take 2, 3 or even 4 bytes depending on your encoding, and also that an INT [will always be 4 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5634104/1291428).

Comment: It is really strange that MySQL does not complain when creating the index. When I did `CREATE INDEX index_keyword ON keyword_links (keyword(333));` it did not give any errors or warnings. It gives an error only when I am trying to add a new column to the table.

Answer (score 0):

Index key will allow only 255 i assume.

Comment: Hmm, not true. I just tried the following: `ALTER TABLE keyword_links DROP INDEX index_keyword;`, `CREATE INDEX index_keyword ON keyword_links (keyword(333));` and it did not fail or give any warnings.

Comment: Warning is becasue it consider only 255 length.