# Failed to read auto-increment value from storage engine, Error Number: 1467

Tags: mysql

When inserting data in mysql i get this error:

Error Number: 1467
   Failed to read auto-increment value from storage engine

I don't now how to solve this issue please any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After some searching i found the answer and it solved my problem.

run this sql query it will fix the problem

```
 ALTER TABLE `YOUR_TABLE`  AUTO_INCREMENT =1
```

Comment: It's a bad approach. What about the existing rows? Consider changing data type as @spencer7593 suggested.

Comment: Knowing how would you solved it would help other people a lot. Could you publish the solution and mark it as the good one please?

Comment: One thing might be useful for the people who are having this issue is to , when adding **auto_increment** default to an existing table, first check if there are already sparse (non-continuous or discrete) value existing for the field you are trying add this attribute to. For my case there has already been existing sparse value in that field and I was getting this error while trying to add this. I had to _truncate_ the table and then add the attribute, as that was a test DB. But it might not be a solution for many of us.

Answer (score 7):

To add a little comment to kiddingmu's answer: it is not just a question of the number of digits, but also of the range of the datatype.
If the column is INT(11), the 11 says that 11 digits are used for display; but this does not release the constraint that [INT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html) can only encode the range -2147483648:2147483647 when signed, and 0:4294967295 when unsigned.

So: for an INT(11) column, an AUTO_INCREMENT of 10000000000 will work; an AUTO_INCREMENT of 90000000000 will not, despite it being 11 digits.

If a larger range is needed, then another type should be used, like [BIGINT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html).

Answer (score 5):

I received this message too.  My problem was that my table was not sorted by index.  Try using the following:

```
ALTER TABLE  `YOUR-TABLE` ORDER BY  `index` ;
```

Comment: yay, thanks, this worked, I spent more time than was needed to find this solution, thank You, thank You

Answer (score 4):

One possible explanation for this behavior is that the autoincrement value has reached the maximum value for the datatype, and its not possible for the database engine to increment it by one.

I suggest you check the current value.  One relatively easy way to do that is to run a `SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable;`, the table definition will show the current value. (You can also query the information_schema.tables view, to get the same information.)

Answer (score 2):

As spencer7593 says, **the autoincrement value has reached the maximum value for the datatype**

I just came to the problem.

use the command **SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;**, I get

```
table name {
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 ......
}ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=100000000000 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

You will see the length of 100000000000 is 12, beyond the limit 11.

Comment: Beware of changing the data type, in my case I changed from int to bigint and even though there was enough size for new values, mysql kept trying to insert into id = 0

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility with this error is that you've hit the max value in the ID field (generally an INT). We had this error when our ID values got close to 4294967295. We ended up having to drop the ID from the table in order to get past the issue. The various INT fields are mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5634147/4573630

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, after changing ID column to id, and after exporting my db, so I just switched the column back to ID and then back to id again, and every thing worked fine after. Working with elequent orm in laravel, it expects column id and I had column ID, that is why I changed it in the first place

Answer (score 0):

**For me it was the auto increment ID(column) that brings about the **Error** **
What i just do to solve it is i drop(delete) the ID column and add it again.

Answer (score 0):

Just alter the table if you are using sequelize run
sync({force: false})

Answer (score -1):

***Check your database structure properly.*** I have also faced this problem, but I found some error in database structure. After fix the structure, problems were resolved.

Answer (score -5):

```
ps aux | grep mysql 
sudo kill (your pid) 
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Comment: Restarting MySql does not address this issue.

Comment: In addition to this answer not being relevant to the post, there's no accompanying commentary. Putting the instructions to restart MySQL without saying what they do is potentially dangerous as it could break things (if the user is a beginner enough to blindly execute instructions without knowing what they do, they are probably unable to fix problems if MySQL does not come back up).