# Weird Auto_increment Issue

Tags: mysql, sql

For some reason my `AUTO_INCREMENT` for my Primary Key column is set to 260 rather than 261. There is already a row with 260 so obviously each query fails to insert.

I tried doing `ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 261` but that gave me another error:

```
Error: Failed to read auto-increment value from storage engine
```

I have tried to drop and re-assign the auto_increment but without success. Only when I reset it back to 260 does it give the duplicate Primary Key error again.

How can I reset this?

Comment: I suppose you already tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690926/failed-to-read-auto-increment-value-from-storage-engine-error-number-1467

Comment: What type is this column? Could you show the `CREATE TABLE` statement?

Comment: @Lashane setting it back to 1?

Comment: @Chris setting to 1, droppping and recreating, there are several such questions

Comment: I suspect the easiest way would be to `CHECK TABLE`, then delete the row with 260, `CHECK TABLE` again, insert row again.