# Mysql zerofill length different from default field length

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL and InnoDB.

I need to store a numeric id which length can vary but needs to be at least 10. For instance:
0000000001
11111111111 are both correct values.

Currently, I my column has the following attributes: bigint(10), unsigned zerofill. This works: if I try to insert "1" then "0000000001" is actually inserted, and if I insert a bigger number (with length>10) it also works.

So, in the end, what is the purpose of the length attribute in the field definition? I thought it was the maximum length, but apparently it is not the case...? Or is my current implementation going to crash eventually?

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634104/what-is-the-size-of-column-of-int11-in-mysql-in-bytes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The length attribute is just a hint for MySQL how to format select query results in the command line client. Nothing more. It has no effect on the datatype actually. An int is an int with 4 bytes, no matter what length you specify. Same of course for bigint, but with 8 bytes.