# How to estimate MYSQL database size for known column range

Tags: mysql

I am trying to estimate database size for know column range. I have searched on it but cant find any proper rules.

I have created a database with single table and this table have 40 Columns. One column is a int primary key and remaining 39 columns are LONGTEXT type.

I am expecting 2 million records.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TempTable` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Column1` longtext,
    `Column2` longtext,
    --
    --
    --

    `Column39` longtext,

  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
)
```

How can I do this? Do I need to insert fake data to calculate the size?

Comment: @RolandStarke ~4 GB for 2 million rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [Data Type Storage Requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-requirements.html) you can estimate the table size:

- The `int` is 4 bytes, note that `(11)` only indicates the maximum number of digits to show (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5634147/1771479)).
- *(L+4)* per string column, *L* being the length in bytes of the string. But note that when you use Unicode (utf8) not all characters use the same number of bytes.

So the size would be:

```
R * ( 4 + 39*(L+4) )
```

With `R` being the number of records, and `L` the average string size.

Taking R=2*10<sup>6</sup> and L=1000 bytes, this gives about:

2*10<sup>6</sup> * ( 4 + 39 ( 1004 ) ) = 7.832 * 10<sup>10</sup> bytes

which is about 72.9 GiB, for other L's:

```
L (bytes)       : 10    100   1000   10000
Table size (GiB):  1    7.5   72.9   726.7
```

Some further notes:

- The actual size depends on the storage engine.
- Some engines also support data compression, such as [InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-compression.html).
- If you use InnoDB it uses 'pages', so the size are multiples of the page size, see [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/118943/78797).
- See this related question: [How to estimate/predict data size and index size of a table in MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46069/how-to-estimate-predict-data-size-and-index-size-of-a-table-in-mysql)