# MySql Data size

Tags: mysql

When i add a column like Data int(11) and i add a value like 1234567810 and i add column like Data varchar(11) and add same value . Which one is small size ? What is the different about it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634104/what-is-the-size-of-column-of-int11-in-mysql-in-bytes

Comment: varchar(11) accommodates upto 11 characters, see the duplicate as to what int(11) is.