# Int variable..I want the alretnative at mysql create table

Tags: mysql

Hi there i  was learn mysql from videos at youtube,and i  want to create table .I have one variable that is a number ,that i want it to be number of the messeges from users.. It is  now int varaible but i found that the max of int is 255.. i want to be bigger what the right varible? 
And is the variable messege text () not null..is right ?

The code is :

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE mssegeFromUsers 
(
NemberMsg INT (255) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 Name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
 Mail VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 Messege TEXT() NOT NULL
 )";
```

I want the massege from user te be long..
It's right?

Comment: Max of `INT UNSIGNED` is `4294967295` - [Integer Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the answer on this question- [What is the size of column of int(11) in mysql in bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634104/what-is-the-size-of-column-of-int11-in-mysql-in-bytes)

`int` will hold 4 bytes of data (so numbers between -2147483648 and 2147483648)

If the number is outside this range, choose either BIGINT (with max of 9223372036854775807) or stick with VARCHAR and set set the character length.

Comment: Thank you, is that mean its will save the masseges at numbers 1,2,3,4 .....2147483648..i

Comment: Yes, any number between -2147483648 and 2147483648 will fit in an INT column. Eg. 100 or 1000000 or 1000000000