# MySQL bigint storage inconsistencies when converting IPv4 to IPv6 / Signed versus Unsigned

Tags: mariadb

I have the following MySQL database table:

```
CREATE TABLE `example` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`ip` BIGINT(11) NOT NULL,
`ipv6` VARBINARY(16) NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

My goal is simply to copy/convert the existing IPv4 IP addresses in to IPv6 format in the new `ipv6` column. So I run the following query which worked just fine in all my test cases:

```
UPDATE example SET ipv6 = INET6_ATON(INET_NTOA(ip));
```

This *should* be simple right? No... After processing 1,083 records MariaDB returns the following error:

> Column 'ipv6' cannot be null.

I'm thinking odd so I decide to start verifying the data:

- There are 1279 records in this table.
- All records contain a value for the `ip` column so that seems good. So I scroll down to the first record which did *not* convert. It has a value of `40036798809` which is 11 numbers so that *should* match up with `INT(11)` right?
- However the second row that was not processed (keeping in mind that MySQL naturally executed the `UPDATE` query going in the ascending order of the primary key `id`) that the `ip` value for that record is `10317637058914` which is 14 numbers long which is *not* supposed to be possible in an `INT(11)` field, correct?
- I see some other integers that are clearly exceeding the integer length so I decide to `ORDER` the table by the `ip` in **HeidiSQL** and then suddenly the highest value record for the `ip` column is `1202623438`. That is ten numbers in length. **phpMyAdmin** also shows the larger number however I have switched to HeidiSQL since I find it's GUI is superior for my local development.
- After some research it appears that the length of the datatype for `BIGINT` has nothing to do with column range. **HeidiSQL** changes the `ip` column values by simply changing the `ORDER`!
  [image: Wait, what?!]
- My next step after continued reading was to check whether the column is signed or unsigned. As **HeidiSQL** shows that the `ip` column is not checked for Unsigned that implies that the `ip` column *is* signed and therefore it's maximum value is (all commas added *only* for visualization, actual values are purely numeric) 2,147,483,647 while the value that would not parse during the `UPDATE` query is 40,036,798,809.
- Earlier research suggested that if a number in the column is larger than what is allowed (not sure why that would even *be* allowed?) then it would be treated as the maximum allowed value (I imagine in this case 2,147,483,647); is this true?

**The Question(s)**

- In summation: why won't the `UPDATE` query parse the entire table?
- Which depends on: what is the problem with MySQL and/or HeidiSQL with storing values?
- Will MariaDB / MySQL allow the storage of numbers larger than what the table structure allows?
- How is is the value 40,036,798,809 (again, without commas) being treated during the `UPDATE` query if the `ip` column type is `BIGINT(11)`?
- What would be the effective value stored for the highest valid IPv4 IP address (255.255.255.255)?
- I presume when I `ORDER` in HeidiSQL that it is showing the *effective* highest value; is this best-guess accurate?

[image: IPv4 to IPv6 Conversion Issue Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Your number 40,036,798,809 seems to be larger than the maximum possible ipv4 address `255.255.255.255`, which yields `4.294.967.295` (or `0xFFFFFFFF`) or largest unsigned longint. So it cant possibly be an IPV4 address, hence the null, hence the error.

Maybe some of your numbers are not IPV4 addresses ?

As for your MySQL Integer column sizes, I sense some confusion there with its byte sizes. You can read up at [What is the size of column of int(11) in mysql in bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634104/what-is-the-size-of-column-of-int11-in-mysql-in-bytes) on that subject.

Comment: I've been working to deploy proper direct IPv6 (with complete absence of IPv4 such as through tunnels) the past couple of days. I am now curious if I can convert to IPv6 from that though?

Comment: in theory, yes, sure, if all your equipment supports ipv6. I'm not too sure on how practical it would be tho. certainly not if you run a website and expect it to be reachable by all internet.

Comment: No, I said IPv6 *support* as in fully tested *without* IPv4 on a connection, *not* that I would drop IPv4 support. Any way I'm trying to see if I can salvage the larger integers; this doesn't seem to work though: `UPDATE example SET ipv6 = IF (INET6_ATON(INET_NTOA(ip)) IS NULL,INET6_NTOA(ip),INET6_ATON(INET_NTOA(ip)));`

Comment: what INET6_ATON returns seems binary, not a number. Try something like this: `update example set ipv6=inet6_aton(coalesce(inet_ntoa(ip), inet6_ntoa(ip), 0));`

Answer (score 0):

Your conversion is correct; your *data* is wrong.  IPv4 involves 32-bit numbers; you have things stored in your `BIGINT` bigger than 32 bits.

This will locate the bad rows:

```
SELECT ip FROM example WHERE ip > INET_ATON('255.255.255.255');
```

You will probably find 196 (1279-1083) bad rows.

The `(11)` is totally unused and irrelevant (unless you have `ZEROFILL`).