# phpMyAdmin doesn't save INT correctly

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

(After sending AJAX / *$http* POST request from AngularJS to PHP) **I am trying to save unix timestamp (as `INT`) in my database**, but it doesn't work.

It comes from JavaScript in this form: `(new Date()).valueOf()`, producing a value in my object: `time_stamp : 1513079761979`. When it arrives in my PHP I can echo it (as JSON, for debugging) and see it as `... : 1513079761979`.

So far the value has not been altered. However, when I `INSERT` it into my database along with some other values, which work fine, including integers, it saves it as `2147483647`, which is obviously is no longer the same value. There are now 10 digits so I thought the length was too short, but nope.

To fix it, I tried all sorts of methods: casting `(int)` in PHP, changing type of attribute to `int(32)` (bigger length) in my database. **Nothing works**.

The only solution I see is to save my integer as string (`VARCHAR` or length 1024~), which does work, but I want to know why it fails to accept `INT` as is, because I have other variables that I'm saving as integers, so I want to guarantee that those work as expected too.

Comment: `Int` will accept only 9 digit number, if you want to insert more than 9 digit number then please use `Big Int`.

Comment: @Ayyappaamara why is the INT type selected as `int(11)` by default? does it still limit to 9 digits?

Comment: read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634104/what-is-the-size-of-column-of-int11-in-mysql-in-bytes) for reference.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html you will find your `2147483647` number on this page. Also use Unsigned if you don't expect negative numbers to increse your storage range.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay , @Scuzzy thank you for those links, that cleared it for me, also the issue was solved with `BIGINT`

Comment: also, it may be worth converting your timestamps to date objects for MySQL, you may get some benefit from the date functions when searching/returning

Comment: @AlekseySolovey, happy to help. Happy coding.