# how to store a 10 digit number into sql bigint datatype?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

When I try to enter value through PHP, 2147483647 is getting stored.

NOTE: 2147483647 is the max size for int datatype not bigint in mysql.

Comment: Please show us the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <your table's name>`.

Comment: Can you edit your question? It makes no sense. I think you left out a critical part of the sentence, including the actual question.

Comment: `CAST(<source> AS BIGINT)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the size of column of int(11) in mysql in bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634104/what-is-the-size-of-column-of-int11-in-mysql-in-bytes)

Comment: There's something you are not clearly indicating. How exactly are you inserting the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maximum value that can be stored in MySQL **`INT`** datatype is `2147483647`.

MySQL will silently truncate larger values down to the maximum supported value.

This is expected (i.e. documented) behavior.

Reference:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html

```
datataype     maximum signed value
---------     --------------------
TINYINT                        127
SMALLINT                     32767
MEDIUMINT                   388607
INT                     2147483647
BIGINT                      2^63-1
```

If we are seeing this behavior storing to a `BIGINT` column, then somewhere in the code path, the value got converted to `INT` datatype, which truncated the value, before the value was assigned to the `BIGINT` column.  This could occur as the return from a function call, or in an assignment of the value in a TRIGGER, et al.

It's not possible to more precisely diagnose the issue with the information provided.

---

How to store a value to a `BIGINT` column?

We can send a string literal in a SQL statement. As a demonstration, twelve decimal digits

```
 CREATE TABLE foo (mycol BIGINT); 
 INSERT INTO foo (mycol) VALUES ('987645312745');
 SELECT mycol FROM foo;

         mycol
 -------------
  987645312745
```

Answer (score 1):

I see no issue:

```
create table my_number (
  val bigint
);

insert into my_number (val) values (1234567890);
insert into my_number (val) values (123456789012345678);

select * from my_number;
```

Result:

```
val                   
----------------------
1234567890            
123456789012345678
```

**Edit: Adding new example posted as comment:**

```
CREATE TABLE contacts_db (
  Fname varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  Lname varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  Email varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  Phone bigint(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
);

insert into contacts_db (Fname, Lname, Email, Phone) 
                 values ('a', 'b', 'c', 1234567890);
insert into contacts_db (Fname, Lname, Email, Phone) 
                 values ('d', 'e', 'f', 123456789012345678);

select * from contacts_db;
```

Result:

```
Fname  Lname  Email  Phone
-----  -----  -----  ------------------
a      b      c      1234567890
d      e      f      123456789012345678
```

Still works well.

Comment: Which is why you should post this as a comment or vote to close the question as no-repro.

Comment: SQL QUERY to create this table ::  CREATE TABLE `contacts_db` (
  `Fname` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `Lname` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `Phone` bigint(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
);

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for answering the question. The problem was due to a typecasting done on the PHP side, by mistake I typecasted the value to (int) while retrieving the input from HTML page.