# mysql get length of data type (int(11) => 11)

Tags: mysql

I don't know if its possible, but I want to get the length of a datatype in MySQL.

[image]

So the type is a int(11) and I know how to get the type back with the query:

`SELECT DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`

it will return a list of

```
[
  int, varchar
]
```

but now I want to get the length of the int back. So what I want to achieve is this:

```
[ int =>  11, varchar  =>  45]
```

[image]

To make it more clear. if i edit the structure of the table.
You will see this page.
i want to get the first 3 columns of this table structure.
This if for frontend purposes.

Please suggest me a query to get this result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the size of column of int(11) in mysql in bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634104/what-is-the-size-of-column-of-int11-in-mysql-in-bytes)

Comment: hi, no it doesn't i changed the question to make it more clear

Comment: Use this to find the `SELECT count(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where DATA_TYPE = "bigint"` to get the total integer filed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS has a lot of information. Please see example here:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/umz2GYQ6U3XEpcTjFs8nYg/0

So, you should select not only DATA_TYPE. You can use COLUMN_TYPE or CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH.

Comment: thnx, that really helped a lot. do you have a query that gets the name, type and max_lenght of all table headers in a table?

Comment: The CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH is only about VARCHAR columns. For INTEGER columns look the article https://nexladder.com/blog/what-does-int11-means-in-mysql/