# How to update MySQL field length in all referenced constraints?

Tags: mysql, constraints, amazon-aurora

I am working on MySQL - Aurora DB from AWS. I have a table with the primary key field(id) declared as `int(11)`. This key is referenced in a lot of other tables.

The problem is that this field is reaching for its maximum value of 11 digits. My questions is: How can i update all the constraints to `int(20)`? The only thing that comes to my mind is to temporary delete all constraints, then change the values and finally add the constraints again. This will take me a lot because i have a million of data stored in my db.

Comment: You have misunderstood the definition please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634104/what-is-the-size-of-column-of-int11-in-mysql-in-bytes

Comment: Disable the conastraints and use bigint and achange all  manually there can't be that many tables involved

Comment: @P.Salmon what should i do when my field reaches 4294967295?