# MySQL actual storage size required for int type 4 bytes or 8 bytes?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I've got a table with following structure

```
CREATE TABLE `data`(
  `id` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `foreign_id_1` INT NOT NULL,
  `foreign_id_2` INT NOT NULL,
  `foreign_id_3` INT NOT NULL,
  `start_dt` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `end_dt` DATETIME,
  `duration_s` INT
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Calculated size of 1 row is 36 bytes: 4x5 + 2x8. 4 bytes per INT field and 8 bytes per DATETIME field.

However, when I inserted 5 000 000 rows into this table actual size of .idb table file was 268 MB. Thus one row used approximately 56 bytes: 268 MB / 5 000 000 ~ 56.2036

Any ideas why this happens? Does INT actually uses 8 bytes instead of 4 (8x5 + 2x8=56)? I couldn't find any mention of this behaviour in documentation or existed SO questions.

MySQL Server version: 5.7.26 (x86_64)
OS: Windows 7 64 bits
Storage: SSD 128GB
FileSystem: NTFS

UPDATE

@akina and @Jacques Ramsden rightly pointed out to me that I have forgot about PK size. So I added another one for table "ALTER TABLE `data` ADD INDEX `foreign_id_1_index` (`foreign_id_1`);" and bytes uses per 1 row has increased from 56 bytes to 71 bytes. Total size of table file before additinal index: 268 MB, after: 340 MB.
Looks like 20 additional bytes may be used by PK.

I will close the question in a few hours if there are no more answers

UPDATE 2

From [11.7 Data Type Storage Requirements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html):
"Every table using the NDB storage engine requires a primary key; if you do not define a primary key, a “hidden” primary key is created by NDB. This hidden primary key consumes 31-35 bytes per table record."

Comment: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634104/what-is-the-size-of-column-of-int11-in-mysql-in-bytes?

Comment: *Calculated size of 1 row is 36 bytes: 4x5 + 2x8.* You forget: nullability byte, inner row number, page split/merge threshold...

Comment: @pugmarx yes, have read this question, it mostly about ZEROFILL behaviour.

Comment: @akina, but there is already an explicitly defined primary key. As far as I know, the engine only creates an internal key when there is no one for the table. Yes, I did not include size of INT PK in calculation. Do you know how much space it will required? Is it really 20 bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you got file per table on? If not you may be forgetting that indexes and such have to be built and maintained by the DB for efficacy.

Update:

When a table is created with inonDB file per table. The data file/tablespace contains both the data and the indexes. This could account for your size difference. Note that the more pk or fk entries the more index usage there will be.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply! Yeah, option is set: "innodb_file_per_table=1".

Comment: @VitaliyVasilevI have Updated the answer.

Comment: So... Looks like additional 20 bytes used by primary key? There is none otheres indexes for this table.

Comment: Possibly yes. I am not 100% sure you would have to try to look at the raw data somehow? If that is possible. Only thing I know is... There are other things in the file.  Such as the index's the table structure, the constraints current size. Possibly things such as unwritten transactional cache etc.

Comment: Create the table with 0 entries check the size. Then create a single entry and check the size. Then two entries, then 10 etc you should get an idea of the rate of growth etc.