# Why Mysql INT(10) unsigned column to row.getLong throws exception in jasync-sql

Tags: java, mysql, jasync-sql

INT(10) unsigned in mysql has limit up to 4b+ and when use with getLong of row, it throws the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at com.github.jasync.sql.db.RowData$DefaultImpls.getLong(RowData.kt:48) ~[jasync-common-0.9.23.jar:?]
    at com.github.jasync.sql.db.general.ArrayRowData.getLong(ArrayRowData.kt:5) ~[jasync-common-0.9.23.jar:?]
    at com.richdevt.hthookserver.repository.ProjectRepository.findProjectEnvironment(ProjectRepository.kt:29) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.richdevt.hthookserver.repository.ProjectRepository$findProjectEnvironment$3.invokeSuspend(ProjectRepository.kt) ~[classes/:?]
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:32) [kotlin-stdlib-1.3.21.jar:1.3.21-release-158 (1.3.21)]
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:233) [kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.1.1.jar:?]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute$$$capture(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163) [netty-common-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java) [netty-common-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404) [netty-common-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:495) [netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:905) [netty-common-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) [netty-common-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_152
```

Why is the conversion not possible?

Answer (score 2):

The type `INT(10) UNSIGNED` is in the size of int (4 bytes) and unsigned: [What is the maximum size of int(10) in Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879345/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-int10-in-mysql)

However, Java has no such type (ie the maximum value is bigger than the maximum Java int). On the other hand, the type returned from MySQL is INT as defined here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html without additional info about unsigned. In such case [jasync-sql](https://github.com/jasync-sql/jasync-sql) converts it to a regular Int type. More details are here: https://github.com/jasync-sql/jasync-sql/issues/102

As a workaround for such case it is possible to do a widening conversion like suggested here: [Best way to convert a signed integer to an unsigned long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578639/best-way-to-convert-a-signed-integer-to-an-unsigned-long)