# VARCHAR optimisation then update

Tags: mysql

If I set a column as varchar(50) say, then update it with a string of length 20 say.  Then OPTIMISE it.  What will happen if I then UPDATE it with a string of more than 20, say 30?

(because the optimise is supposed to get rid of excess baggage on the varchars...)

Second question:  What happens if I have a varchar(50) and UPDATE with a string of 51 characters?

Third question:  The manual is unclear here, but what is the true maximum optimal string size for varchar?  is it 256 or 254 (because of the extra 2 bytes it needs) or is it something else?

> "In contrast to CHAR, VARCHAR values are stored as a one-byte or
>   two-byte length prefix plus data. The
>   length prefix indicates the number of
>   bytes in the value. A column uses one
>   length byte if values require no more
>   than 255 bytes, two length bytes if
>   values may require more than 255
>   bytes."

Thanks.

Comment: "What happens if I have a varchar(50) and UPDATE with a string of 51 characters?" : try it, it should truncate the extra characters.

Comment: about 256 or 254 (256 is impossible) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262238/are-there-disadvantages-to-using-a-generic-varchar255-for-all-text-based-fields

Answer (score 0):

1. optimize does not get rid of excess baggage, it just act like window-defragmented to clean disk-space for bulky delete - [details](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html). If you update with a string with 30 length, mysql just store as what is it, nothing more and nothing less
2. if you update a string with 51, the last character will be chopped/truncated
3. **that is no optimal string size for varchar**, is much depended on your application usage, and how you work with mysql index. The maximum `varchar(255)` still stay at string at length of 255