# NVARCHAR(MAX) to replace TEXT datatype?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have read about [Are there any disadvantages to always using nvarchar(MAX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148398/are-there-any-disadvantages-to-always-using-nvarcharmax) and [varchar(max) vs varchar(255)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4d9c6504-496e-45ba-a7a3-ed5bed731fcc/varcharmax-vs-varchar255?forum=sqlgetstarted) from different forums. Now, I wonder if it is *ideal/safe* practice to convert a `text` datatype to `nvarchar(MAX)`? Are there any performance difference? or do I need to specify the size (as in`nvarchar(255)`) instead of `nvarchar(max)`?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512164/is-varcharmax-always-preferable

Comment: If you know the size is less than 4000 (or 8000 for `varchar()`), then you should use the smaller value.  But, if `text` was used in an old version of SQL Server, then the right replacement is `max`.

Comment: I don't actually know the actual length since it is migrated from another database. BTW, it came from SQL Server 2000. I am having problems in migrating triggers when I try to create using the `text` datatype. Just to be safe, I want to know if it has a negative impact if I use `nvarchar(MAX)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer is very simple: `text` type is deprecated. So, yes, you should  convert a `text` datatype to `varchar(MAX)`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms187993.aspx

> ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version
>   of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new
>   development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use
>   them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.

On top of that, if you know that the size of your `text` is less than 8000, then use `varchar(nnn)` instead of `varchar(max)`. `varchar(nnn)` is more efficient than `varchar(max)`.

Note: `text` type is for non-unicode text, so use `varchar` instead. `ntext` is for unicode text, so use `nvarchar` instead.

Comment: I think the point of the original poster's question is more around what are the downsides (if any) of using NVARCHAR(max) instead of TEXT. I can think of one, and that is the act of converting itself. If you're doing it on a big, busy table that has to be up 24/7, your average DBA or developer might baulk at the prospect and leave well enough alone. The cost of developing and thoroughly testing a conversion might frighten people too. In a risk-averse organisation, the safety of doing nothing might outweigh the benefits of any change.