# CHAR vs VARCHAR for password security

Tags: sql, char

Are there any benefits of CHAR over VARCHAR for storing passwords?

I have hunted high and low but can't find anything on this.

I ask because I have been told to use CHAR for passwords and am intrigued as to why.

Answer (score 3):

Do your passwords have a max length constraint? If they do, you should have no need for `varchar`.

In any case, if you are storing passwords, you should be hashing them and storing the hash. Many hashing algorithms hash to a fixed size so I don't think char should be an issue here. Just allocate the appropriate amount of characters.

Whatever you do, make sure you hash them!

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in security. The difference is in the storage mechanism.

From the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html):

> The following table illustrates the differences between CHAR and VARCHAR by showing the result of storing various string values into CHAR(4) and VARCHAR(4) columns (assuming that the column uses a single-byte character set such as latin1).

```
Value       CHAR(4) Storage Required    VARCHAR(4)  Storage Required
''          ''      4 bytes             ''          1 byte
'ab'        'ab '   4 bytes             'ab'        3 bytes
'abcd'      'abcd'  4 bytes             'abcd'      5 bytes
'abcdefgh'  'abcd'  4 bytes             'abcd'      5 bytes
```

So you can see that `VARCHAR` is beneficial if the length of the string that you are storing is variable. The reason why `CHAR` is often used for password fields is because the output of hashing algorithms is consistent regardless of the length of input. Since you are storing a hash of the user's password, and not the password itself, the field length will be consistent.

leeor is correct in advising you to hash passwords. [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/#password_hashing) is a good resource for best practices in that regard.