# Max length of "tzname" field / timezone identifier name

Tags: database, timezone, schema

I am trying to find the max length of a timezone identifier. This is the string used as the timezone name (e.g. "America/New_York"). The tz database is not helpful; I could not find implementation details.

[Microsoft (.NET Framework 4.5) suggests a max length of 32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.id.aspx), but this seems to be a limitation of their registry.

[libc points to a limit called "_POSIX_TZNAME_MAX", which is 3 characters long](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Minimums.html), but this is an absolute minimum requirement for POSIX compliance. Typically, I guess an implementation will use more.

So the real question is: What's an acceptable string length to safely store timezone "tzname" / identifier name?

Comment: The Microsoft .NET Framework `TimeZone.Id` property is for Windows' time-zone identifiers which are very different from IANA tzdb identifiers.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Why not use a container that doesn't care what the length is -- as e.g. `std::string` ?

Now, it so happens that I was working recently with the TZ db as supplied in the common csv format (eg here [in a file from Boost](https://github.com/boost-vault/date_time/blob/master/date_time_zonespec.csv)) but the same format is also used in the Boost sources.

With that data, I am seeing a maximum length of 28:

```
R> library(RcppBDT)                      # R package interfacing Boost Date_Time
Loading required package: Rcpp
R> tz <- new(bdtTz, "America/Chicago")   # init. an object, using my default TZ
R> tznames <- tz$getAllRegions()         # retrieve list of all TZ names
R>
R> length(tznames)                       # total number of TZ identifiers
[1] 381
R>
R> head(tznames)                         # look at first six
[1] "Africa/Abidjan"     "Africa/Accra"       "Africa/Addis_Ababa" 
[4] "Africa/Algiers"     "Africa/Asmera"      "Africa/Bamako"     
R>
R> summary(sapply(tznames, nchar))       # numerical summary of length of each
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
      9      13      15      15      17      28 
R>
R> tznames[ nchar(tznames) >= 26 ]       # looking at length 26 and above
[1] "America/Indiana/Indianapolis" "America/Kentucky/Louisville"  
[3] "America/Kentucky/Monticello"  "America/North_Dakota/Center" 
R>
```

We can also look at a histogram:

```
R> library(MASS)
R> truehist(sapply(tznames, nchar), 
+           main="Distribution of TZ identifier length", col="darkgrey")
R>
```

[image]

This uses code which I have in my RcppBDT package's [SVN repo on R-Forge](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/RcppBDT/?root=rcpp) but not yet in the [CRAN version](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppBDT) of the package.

Comment: Amazing answer! Actually, I cannot use variable length strings because I want to store those strings in a database. At first, I did not want to use an arbitrarily-long char field, but I think I am set on a 40-char long string[1]. I will put these in a separate table and refer to them using foreign keys.

1: There is a timezone ("America/Argentina/ComodRivadavia") that is actually 32-char long. In the future there might be other equally-long names.

Comment: Can't you use varchar in SQL?

Comment: Don't varchars actually require a specified length?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59667/why-would-i-ever-pick-char-over-varchar-in-sql -- you want varchar just as I said right at the beginning :)

Comment: You're absolutely right, thank you. Do you think a VARCHAR size 40 leaves enough space for future timezone names?

Comment: I'd say so. I am not sure whether varchar(N) (for some value of N) really is preferable to just varchar.

Comment: The longest name I can find in my local zoneinfo directory is `right/America/Argentina/ComodRivadavia` (38 chars). Besides all `right/...` there are also `posix/...` names. Those names are explained [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/34957/6969).

Comment: Is just VARCHAR even valid SQL? I thought a size was mandatory. If it isn't, maybe that's database-specific, in which case that's a good reason to specify the number - if you specify a value too high for the database you're using, you will find out now, instead of when someone tries to insert it. :)

Comment: varchar by itself in some databases, like SQL Server, implies the varchar(max) or a max length varchar (not good). I just do a healthy round up to an even, recognizable, power of 2 in a bid to be safe and at least have the semblance of reason. I'm going with 64 in this case.